# How to deal with newbies on Stack Exchange websites

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, answers, new-users

Is this the good behaviour ?

> **I don't care** if the post comes from a newbie or grizzled veteran - if it is a good post I will upvote it, if it is a bad post, **I will vote it down**.

- Why not act to change or improve the post ?
- why not write a comment ?
- Why just downvote it ?

Those people who act based on "good" or "bad" post, should re-think their behaviour and think about "correct" or "wrong" post.

---

---

I'm not a top level computer hacker or programming engineer, far from it, but I am reading some very "poor" questions, answers and comments in many Stack Exchange websites.

The questions and answers are not "self created", some real person wrote it. We are in fact dealing with people.

What if the newbies in the Stack Exchange community did have an obligatory experience in a place where they will be forced to reach some reputation (like 10 or 25) before make a question or write an answer in the others Stack Exchange website?

The obvious answer to this question: NO! That place will be fulled of newbies "teaching" the wrong behaviour to each other!

What if the newbies did have an obligatory poll to answer, and must achieve some result, like 90% of correct answer in that poll, to get the privilege to make question and post answer?

Based on the questions, answers and comments, some people will blame it and post an answer: "this is to hard to make and not so useful" others will answer "why they don't read the help page?", the newbies will answer "this is a good idea", and a few people will write as a comment "this is a good/bad idea"

And, another topic that many people has concerns is about downvotes and upvotes. I saw some correct answers with downvotes, some incorrect answers with no downvotes, and some incorrect answers with upvotes.

Some people has fear about to be pursued (or wish to pursue) by people based on votes.

So, how to deal with newbies in Stack Exchange websites?

Comment: Sure! You can also ask people for a proof they got 1600 in [SAT exam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT) before they are allowed to post a question or answer on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Possibly related: [Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/997587)

Answer (score 21):

> So, how to deal with newbies in stackexchange's websites ?

You don't.

What you *do* deal with are poor questions and answers. I don't care if the post comes from a newbie or grizzled veteran - if it is a good post I will upvote it, if it is a bad post, I will vote it down.

I have seen many good questions written by total newbies (by which I mean people who have not posted on our sites before - can't really take their experiences elsewhere into account, given we don't know anything about them).

On the other hand, I have seen truly awful questions written by people with tens and hundreds of thousands of reputation points.

---

In short: newness or reputation doesn't give you any indication about the possible quality of a future post by a person. Making any sort of posting policy based on them is bad.

Comment: If only the bad newb posts, those from 'programmers' who are neither professional nor enthusiast. did get questions closed.  Failure to grasp basic language syntax does not seem to be much of a barrier to getting hopelessly bad syntax fixed by the rep-personalServicesWorkers:(

Comment: the questions and answers are not "self created", some real person wrote it. We are in fact dealing with people.

Comment: @CorreadaSilva - indeed. But deciding on whether someone should or should not post simply based on "reputation" is not feasible. Shunting them off to a different section isn't a great idea either - the only people who would go to such a section are those without reputation...

Comment: 'some real person wrote it', sure, usually the prof/TA who set the homework, or the other student who had their half-completed work copied.  Good newb questions do occasionally happen, but they float on top of a sea of gunge.

Comment: I have decades of experience in software development and ~20k rep, (when I'm not suspended for objecting to 'i++ + ++i' newb questions:), but two of my five questions are, well, lets not talk about them at all ;(    I'm afraid that skilled and experienced users merely serve up a slightly different smell of garbage, and so I have to agree with Oded.

Comment: @Oded `But deciding on whether someone should or should not post simply based on "reputation" is not feasible.` Well, we already do that.  We have stricter rate limits for users without rep, the whole idea of protected questions, etc.  This question also isn't proposing that either, or asking for them to be pushed elsewhere.  Your answer simply has nothing to do with the question being asked here.  It's not asking if we should downvote new users just because they're new, it's asking if we should put systems in place to ensure people only ask questions when they know how to.

Comment: @MartinJames, you has 457 points of reputation and said "I have decades of experience in software development and ~20k rep" ?!

Comment: @CorreadaSilva - 457 reputation on this site. Martin has over 20k on Stack Overflow (well, pre-suspension).

Comment: @Oded How do you know that if he didn't mention Stack Overflow ? Or you just go to Martin's account to seek something after my comment ?

Comment: @CorreadaSilva - because it is a sentence about software development experience. Wouldn't make sense in the context of this site, but perfect sense in the context of Stack Overflow.