# Come Take a Look at our New Contributor Indicator!

Tags: discussion, new-users, announcements, new-contributor-indicator

> This feature is now live across the network.

We've been doing quite a bit of research into ways that we could help new users have better experiences that ultimately lead them to becoming increasingly valuable, long-term contributors to our sites. While this is still ongoing, it's starting to blossom in the form of small but hopefully *very* effective changes we can make to improve how well we retain great people.

We're very enthusiastic about a new change that's small in scope, but big in potential to help new contributors find their footing. Coming very soon: ***our shiny (new) new contributor indicator!***

[image: New contributor indicator screenshot]

> `tl;dr;`: Folks will see an indicator when they go to interact with new contributors (visible for a week following their first post) letting them know that the person is new. A handy link to our [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) will be in the notification for reference.

#### What are our goals with this?

- Help develop and reinforce empathy for new contributors
- Help new contributors overcome anxiety surrounding asking or answering their first question on our sites

#### Here's a little more background:

We actively discourage folks from providing information that isn't really relevant to their posts; we would rather folks just get down to business. That's fine, but it doesn't really solve for how apprehensive people feel when contributing to a new community (especially one that's notorious for having lots of rules).

We tend to edit out ways that people try to anticipate and address criticism in advance (stop me if you've heard this one!):

> ***I'm really new at this, so please forgive me if I'm doing this incorrectly ...***

Sometimes, people say this because they're new at *two* skills: whatever they're trying to accomplish *and* (in many cases) asking questions on our sites. Sometimes, they're experienced in endeavor, they're just new to our engine. The need for a little empathy is the *same* however, and equally applicable in either case. We agree that this sort of stuff doesn't belong in posts, but we feel like the system should embrace it.

This indicator can speak *for* new contributors in a friendly way that the system itself reinforces; we hope it will allow folks to feel less apprehensive about jumping in.

If you're thinking something along the lines of 'Student Driver', the analogy generally fits: black-and-yellow striped tape and everything.

#### What is it going to look like?

Well, it's not going to be black-and-yellow striped tape, even though that would be pretty neat. It's easier to just show you, so I brought some screenshots! While these are still being finalized and tweaked, here's what the indicator will look like when you:

**Comment on any of their initial posts, or view their initial questions:**

[image: New user indicator mock up - comment on question prompt]

*Note: the new indicator doesn't actually attach to the user card throughout the site; it only appears where the user card is displayed on posts. This is what happens if you mouse over the indicator:*

[image: new user indicator mouseover mock up]

---

**Or, write an answer to their initial questions:**

[image: new user indicator answer question mock up]

*.. and the indicator under the user card on answers behaves just like it does in the question view example.*

---

These are the most *common* pain points when it comes to engaging with new contributors.

#### The new indicator doesn't alter functionality.

It's a reminder that how you interact with the person could be *extra* meaningful (any time we help strangers just out of the love for what we do, it's meaningful). But it's not a magic shield of any kind, it doesn't work like spawn protection (where players can't take damage for the first few seconds after entering) in video games.

#### The new indicator works by the age of a user's first visible post.

This could be a question or answer, and the association bonus won't influence the behavior. While you might not be new to our engine, everyone is new when they first join a new community, so the indicator is shown.

#### What behavior do we hope to encourage from more experienced users?

We hope folks will try to explain the *why* in addition to the *what* or *how* when you show new folks the ropes of using our system, and try to make them feel like it's within their immediate capability to be successful here. Experienced contributors don't need to know that their formatting looks good when you mention that they forgot to include a version number, but new contributors really appreciate that encouragement.

Other things you can do:

- Flag comments that are unfriendly or simply unhelpful. New users can do this now on posts that they own, but let's show people that we're serious about investing as much in them as they do in us. Snark sets a bad impression, but snark vanishing quickly sets a much better one.
- Don't add to 'pile on' scenarios of any kind; let moderators know if something needs immediate attention.
- Help new users by *editing* their posts, and leaving them a comment explaining how your edit improved things.
- Don't forget to upvote posts that you feel have value. It's strange when a question gets *three plus* answers, yet not a single vote. There's no obligation, of course, but the indicator is a helpful reminder.

#### Why are we doing this?

Our sites work in a way where it's nearly impossible to guide new users through complete onboarding in a way where we can *ensure* that they avoid all major pitfalls. There are just *too many* nuances to how the system works that can't be sufficiently expressed in UX / system dialog; we need a safety net.

We like to take [the least invasive approach](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) that's likely to get the job done when it comes to guiding behavior, so we don't want to make changes to tools when a simple sign that says "Hey, those things are sharp, be careful!" would suffice.

Questions? Suggestions? Feedback? Let us know.

Comment: The comments were overwhelming the answers. This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1236/discussion-on-question-by-tim-post-come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indic).

Comment: We're going to be looking at quite a few things posted here, _but we're not going to make many (if any) changes beyond bug fixes until we have established some base data_. At that point, we'll try tweaking things. I'm now locking this post for comments, because they've been getting ***way*** out of hand.

Comment: Just popping in to note that the new user indicator does not count deleted posts. I posted in the Worldbuilding Meta sandbox, then deleted the answer per the rules. Many months later I asked a question, and the indicator showed up. Not sure if it's a problem or not; it's just not entirely accurate in that instance. Thought I would mention it in case it is of interest.

Comment: Does the new user see those indicators?  It seems like their situation would be a bit more friendly if they didn't, but I am not sure.

Comment: I took a look and added the indicator to the block list, alongside to the hot newtork questions, blog announcements, job ads and whatever dross you've put in the left sidebar.

Comment: "This indicator can speak for new contributors in a friendly way that the system itself reinforces" There are a few years of data now. Has this indicator has any impact on the rate at which new contributors explicitly say it anyway (which is noise that we're supposed to edit out of posts)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the OP here is no longer working for SE and has no way to answer your question. Try asking it as a new question, and there's a tiny chance current SE staff will notice it and reply. (They're very busy.)

Comment: Ah, I hadn't actually looked at the name. [It's really been more than two years now, wow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356603/a-big-thank-you-tim-post).

Answer (score 436):

I'm on board with the idea of reminding people to be considerate to those who are new to the site, but I think there's a piece missing.  The new UI element encourages established users to help the new user understand site norms, but I don't see where the *system* tries to help the new users understand it.

Yes, there's the Help Center, but we already know that way too many users don't read it - and a lot of the information there is not needed before somebody posts a question!  I don't need instructions on what to do when somebody answers *until after somebody answers*.  The Help Center simply pushes too much information on the user all at once.

[HDE's suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314291/291308) for canned comments are great, but several of those could be automatically generated by the system as a new user needs to see them.  The system itself needs to encourage established users to provide good feedback to new users, but also needs to encourage the new users to look for, understand, and act on that feedback.

The first time a new user's post is edited, they need to get a notification that says something like:

> Another user has edited your post.  You can view the edit summary to see what they changed and read the comments on why they did so.  You can also add a comment to your post using @[username] to request more information on why they modified your post.

Make the words "edit summary" link directly to the edit history for their post.  Fill in the username of the editor so it is easy for them to copy/paste a response if they think something is wrong.

Then give editors a complementary prompt when editing a new user's post:

> Dan is a new contributor.  Please be sure that your edit summary includes *specific feedback* on the changes you made so that Dan can understand how to write better posts in the future.

For bonus points, add a couple of checkboxes that the editor can select for common changes (formatted code, changed tags, removal of salutations and "thanks in advance," etc.) and produce canned feedback that expands on those themes.  An edit summary that says "remove fluff" gives little feedback to the user, and writing a longer edit summary is a pain for the editor.  Make it so that the editor only has to check a box and the new user gets an extra paragraph in the edit summary explaining the "no fluff" policy, with links to the relevant help center page.

The same kind of logic applies to other actions that are typical for new users to experience.

- If they get a down vote, explain to them what that means and link to the help center article on voting.  Review the info on how to write a good post.
- As comments start coming in, encourage them to read the comments to see if there is feedback on how they can improve their post.  Make sure they understand how/why to flag comments.
- Make sure they see a notification about close votes that explains *what* close votes have been cast and *how* they should modify their post to alleviate the issues.
- If their question *is* closed, provide a long-form explanation of the close vote reason and suggest next actions.  If it's a duplicate, make sure they understand *that's okay*.  If their question is "too broad," provide a help center link that shows examples of how broad questions can be reworked into clear, answerable ones.
- When somebody answers, provide a tip about how to upvote or accept answers, *and* include guidance on how long to wait before accepting an answer.

**tl;dr Build the new user experience so that *it* explains how to use the site instead of relying on users to "be nice" by explaining it to them.**

*Disclaimer: I haven't done the "new user" experience in a while.  Apologies if any of these have already been implemented.*

Comment: I really like these; I think they do a good job of filling in some of the gaps left by the [Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682/6535830), in its current form - they seem really good at guiding the user through the rest of the experience after writing a post.

Comment: **This.**  This times a thousand.  This addresses the problem where it actually sits—educating new users on how to *use the site* should be handled *by the site,* not by experienced users.  If this is properly done, the irritation about new users doing things wrong will vanish because they will simply know better.

Comment: I want to award a bounty to this answer; it's exemplary.  Please remind me when the question is eligible.

Comment: BJ Myers, I recommend you add a "tl;dr" at the top, and use some tasteful bolding on the key sentences.  This answer is a gem and I *really* hope Stack Exchange decides to go with this approach instead of the "noob" flags.

Comment: This also has the advantage (over canned comments) of not cluttering the comment section, which saves experienced users' time.

Comment: About edit summary: While I agree with the checkbox idea, I don't completely agree with the "new contributor" note. I propose that the "new contributor" note should only be displayed *if the edit summary is left empty* -- if users already leave detailed edit summary then they don't need to know about that, otherwise high-rep users will usually leave it empty, and suggested edits by low-rep users should already have detailed edit summary.

Comment: None of the 5 bullet points is implemented; except option 4 (it's explained in the close banner; however OP receives no notification when their question is closed, so it's not very useful). No need for the disclaimer.

Comment: Now, I __finally__ see a suggestion that looks like it might make a difference for the new users, have minimal impact on the veterans, and make no, or minimal, changes in the general UI. It's also likely too much work for SE to bother with.

Comment: Don't tell new users how to upvote until they have enough rep to upvote, and make sure they know that they can only comment on their own posts initially. Provide site-specific boiler-plate text and links so that, for example, new users can find out how to create an MWE or MWEB if a question on TeX SE gets comments containing any of the keywords 'MWE', 'MWEB', 'minimal working example', 'minimal document', 'what you've tried', 'code to reproduce' etc. Right now, it's a pain to link users to this info because you have to switch to Meta, remember the search term, find the question etc.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Given that SE already provides notification on privilege unlock, I don't think this will take much time.

Comment: The site already does most of these things already.  The issue is that people don't read the information shown to them, not that it isn't shown to them.  Yes, there are a handful of things that the system doesn't do a good job of explaining, and they should have such information added, but it will make very little difference as most of the people who read such things aren't the users causing problems.

Comment: @Servy, "The site already does most of these things already."  **No, it doesn't.**  And my [very simple feature request to implement one of these things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285913/307622) has still not been implemented despite dozens of upvotes.

Comment: @Wildcard I said most, not all.  I also said that there are a few things that the system doesn't explain, and it's fine to add an explanation for them.   Pointing out one thing that you think should be explained in more detail doesn't invalidate any of that.  Also keep in mind that the more banners and popups and messages you present to the user, the less they'll read, so information needs to be curated heavily, and everything considered as to whether or not it's really *that* essential.  People accepting answers apparently didn't meet that burden.  Personally I agree with that assessment.

Comment: "If they get a down vote, explain to them what that means and link to the help center article on voting." Is very, very important, because the most prominent way in which SE is unusual (IMO) is the high visibility of downvotes. But how  would you suggest that this is implemented? Perhaps sending them a notification? Sending notifications for everything is also bad because they could just get confused with an information overload or even end up missing a couple of the links they're sent.

Comment: Agreed, great points. One of our current research/UX initiatives is to look at how the system can better train new folks to participate effectively.

Comment: +1 Also, consider adding a bullet point about *pointing new users to the "on-topic" FAQ when they ask a question*.

Comment: There are some great suggestions here. It's a bit like that tutorial level in a console game where you get irritating prompts telling you how to do basic tasks, which you nonetheless need because otherwise you'd have no idea what you were doing, then once you get to the real levels all the prompting goes away

Comment: The "another user has edited your post" canned message probably ought to also include an explanation of why this is a normal and **good thing**. We get a lot of new users who act like any edit from someone else is a blasphemy against the purity of their post.

Comment: I think this hits the nail on the head. SE does a terrible job of educating new users how to effectively participate in the community. They get a "here's a link over here you wont read" while we're constantly slapped in the face with banners saying "be nice". I was happy it was added to the comments, as that's where the negativity tends to show up; but branding the user, and slapping us again when we try to answer their question is annoying and frankly insulting. We're your user-base, not monsters.

Answer (score 370):

This really isn't adding new information.  Mostly because showing rep provides this information already.  When you see someone with very little rep, the odds of them being within a few days old are *very* high.  People checking their profile or user card *already* know if the user is fairly new or fairly experienced.  The exceptions are...rare, and I don't see this being useful just for the rare exceptional cases.

There's also the fact that a new *account* doesn't mean it's a new user.  Lots of people make new accounts.  Lots of people make new accounts often.  Sometimes for good reasons, sometimes for not so good reasons.  In fact I'm fairly confident that there are more experienced users that would have this banner showing up under their posts then there are inexperienced users with more than, say, 100 rep.

There's really only two reasons to include this information, and in so many places no less.  Either you're trying to get people to treat new users differently in ways you know they're not supposed to (i.e. voting on the user and not the content), or you're showing people a bunch of information that you expect them to just ignore, and thus are intentionally wasting their time.

Showing this information in the answer box is also *particularly* egregious.  People shouldn't be changing how the answer based on how new the question author is, so there's no reason at all to be including this information there.  The only examples you've given of times where people should act differently for a new user are potentially explaining their actions more in comments, so that at least explains why you're showing it in the comment box, but showing it in the answer box doesn't even make sense.

> What are our goals with this?
>
> Help develop and reinforce empathy for new contributors

Why just new users, and not all users?

> Help new contributors overcome anxiety surrounding asking or answering their first question on our sites

Given that the new user is...new, they're not going to *know* that you're doing this, so I don't see how there going to be any less nervous around asking.  Also, I would expect for lots of users having several big giant flashing neon signs saying, "new user" is likely to make them *more* nervous, and removes any chance of them appearing to be an experienced user (or for readers to not even consider how new they are) by simply asking a good question that doesn't make it clear that they don't know what they're doing.  How would this possibly make people *less* nervous?

Comment: Note that "new user" here isn't just creating a new account, as you imply – it is defined as one week after the first post in a particular community (per the OP) .

Comment: @Nathaniel first "visible" post... which does make me wonder what happens if the user asks a question, self-deletes it as they've already solved it or didn't want to post it in the first place, then comes back 3 months later to ask a genuine question - are they still considered as new?

Comment: @Nathaniel I didn't really feel a need to address the possibility of someone creating the account on the site and then not asking a question for a while.  The vast majority of the time they're the same time, or close enough to it.  I'm aware of the criteria the question specifies, but just feel that saying, "user who recently asked their first question" instead of "new user" is just needlessly verbose as it's not a relevant point to what I'm discussing.

Comment: @Shog9 And either way, using 1 rep really skews the results (by limiting the population).  My point is more to consider, say, the average age of an account that has <100 rep when posting a question.  My guess is that the age is pretty low, low enough to consider them, "new" (or even if the time since account creation is high, they've used the site so little that they're still "new to the site", and not a user with a lot of interactions).

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, and your queries are also looking at all of the posts of suspended users.

Comment: Ok, read the first query again @Servy - it's looking at Post CreationDate not User CreationDate. There is a bug though: I used getdate() instead of calculating the data dump creation date as in the other queries; [correct results are 14K](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/888083) not 2K.

Comment: @Shog9 Ah, I did indeed miss that.  Although the point on suspended users still stand, and the fact that your queries aren't really describing what I was referring to in my questions.

Comment: There are at best a trivial number, maybe a couple dozen, posts from suspended users in play here; not that it matters, since you have to look at a user's profile to know that they're suspended - and I'm not the one making the argument that merely looking at their reputation is sufficient. I'll leave it up to you to modify these trivial queries on public data to see what changing 1 to 100 brings you, since you're the one making the claim that this is sufficient in some way for some undefined (in your answer) value of "low reputation".

Comment: @Shog9 So your first query shows that there are ~14k posts from 1 rep users in the past 7 days (as of the time of the dump).  Your second query shows that there are ~1.2k first posts within **1** day of the data dump.  There are [~15k first posts within 7 days of the data dump.](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/888094).  So there are slightly more first posts then there are posts by users with 1 rep over that 7 day period of time.  Of course, this isn't measuring real first posts, just first non-deleted post.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm honestly not sure what either of those queries tells us about how many posts from low rep users are actually experienced users with a lot of past actions.  There isn't a good way to see the amount of rep someone had at the time they posted a post, and since the data dump can't tie deleted posts to a user, we can't (accurately) see how much of a history someone had before asking a given question.  Because we can't compute either of those things, I didn't try to write a data.SE query for them, as the information isn't there.

Comment: Good catch, @Servy; I wrote these in way too much of a hurry. [Here's a combined query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/888116) showing total posts, no-rep, low-rep, new and combinations.

Comment: As for the information not being in SEDE... If it's not in SEDE, it's not on the question page either. Your base argument here is that *showing the author's current reputation* on a post suffices for the purpose of identifying folks who are new / likely inexperienced - but while reputation is probably a good measure of *productive* experience, it's certainly not a good indicator of "new".

Comment: @Shog9 I said that it correlates well enough with "new" to be a good enough approximation.  The cases where it doesn't are rare enough that you don't need this feature to be able to tell who's new.  So yes, it's possible for some people to have a ton of deleted content, and ask a new question, and *look* new when they're not, and thanks to this feature in those rare cases someone could tell that they're not new when they couldn't before.  I don't think that's really that important.  If you think it's a more common case, we'd need info not in SEDE, which only SE itself could provide.

Comment: @Shog9 I suppose the other thing to consider is what's the problem with your average user considering a small handful of users with some previous deleted bad questions to be new users, and as a result, spending a bit more time explaining how their content could be improved or how the site works, rather than seeing that they're experienced and moving on.  If they've had a few bad contributions they clearly don't know how to act appropriately, so it's no bad that they're told how to act appropriately.

Comment: You could argue that the contributor is wasting their time as the user is less likely to be improvable, but if they have so many bad contributions that we don't even think it's worth helping them they'd be question banned, so it would only be users with a small number of bad contributions that look new when they aren't, when using rep over this method.  I think it's perfectly fine to treat such a user as a new user; it shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: I have 14 rep on SO that isn't the association bonus, and I've been there for 3 years. Your point is invalid.

Comment: @Steve I assume you're post banned, given that you have a dozen (at least) poorly received questions.  So it's irrelevant how you appear to people when asking a question because you can't ask questions.  Also I never said that literally every single low rep user is a new user, I said that the two correlate well enough for practical purposes, and that the few exceptional cases aren't a problem.  For example, if someone comments on one of your questions with advice on how to ask a good question, assuming you're new, I don't think that's that bad, as you clearly need said advice.

Comment: @Servy I can ask questions at the moment. My experience is different from that. When I asked questions about basics people generally assumed I was a troll. When I asked for help, people down voted my questions more because they didn't like me trying to improve. This step was needed. I'm what happens when you don't have this stuff around.

Comment: @Steve It's been 6 months since you last asked a question.  You're almost certainly post banned.

Comment: @Servy Yepp 6 months the magic number. Now I can ask questions....

Comment: @Servy I will be able to if it gets 20 upvotes. I'm pretty sure that's the line for me.

Comment: And what about the chronic recycled account: create an account, use for one day; next day: create a second account to re-ask a closed question from the day before, and two more homework questions; next day, create a third account...  ... for weeks on end.  This happens on MSE.  Why should we be using a banner to perpetually rewelcome a serial-account-creator?

Comment: @amWhy I already mentioned that in the answer (see the second paragraph).  Were you meaning to direct that to one of the commentors?

Comment: And let's not forget the effect on experienced, frequently contributing users. This entire welcoming push has been extremely intimidating and put a lot of people on edge to begin with. Now it's being rubbed in their faces even more. So it makes everyone more nervous.

Comment: I upvoted this back in the beginning, but now I'm commenting because apparently that upvote didn't speak loud enough that I agree with this, since it went live anyway. Maybe I should register a new account and comment on it, since that hand makes me LOUDER!

Comment: @jpmc26: _"This entire welcoming push has been extremely intimidating... So it makes everyone more nervous"_ - not everyone. I think it's great, and don't feel nervous at all. If anything, I feel more energized to try a little harder to welcome new users.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's pretty callous to the feelings of your peers. Do you care about making sure people who have been here for years feel welcome? Because an awful lot of us don't anymore. Why are new users more important than them? If you do, what's your solution to making sure they do feel welcome? The point is that a lot of conflict has erupted over this; the overall net effect has been a pretty big increase in frustration and worry.

Comment: @jpmc26: _"That's pretty callous to the feelings of your peers. Do you care about making sure people who have been here for years feel welcome?"_ - absolutely I care about making sure people who have been here for years feel welcome.  _"Why are new users more important than them?"_ - I do not believe they are more important, I just believe they have different needs, and I think this feature helps us to better meet there needs. I'm all for additional measures that help the other people you speak of.

Comment: @jpmc26: _"_"If you do, what's your solution to making sure they do feel welcome?"_ - I don't have a so"_ - I don't have a solution. That's why I trust the maintainers of this site to do research, come up with good ideas, test them out, and then adjust based on the data.  _"The point is that a lot of conflict has erupted over this"_ - I'm not sure it's fair to say "a *lot* of conflict". A dozen or so people out of 100's of thousands, while important, isn't necessarily "a lot".

Comment: @BryanOakley There are not hundreds of thousands of active contributors. There's not more expressing agreement either. Hundreds of people have expressed agreement with the concerns raised on Meta. If we assume that this is some kind of representative sample (a fairly reasonable assumption), you must conclude that some large percentage of those hundreds of thousands are also impacted negatively. I find it insulting that you assume we're some kind of isolated minority that should just be ignored.

Comment: @jpmc26: _" I find it insulting that you assume we're some kind of isolated minority that should just be ignored."_ - I do not assume that. Why are you being so hostile and negative? I absolutely do not believe you should be ignored. Just because I disagree with you does not mean I disrespect you. Neither do I think you should ignore people like me who think this is a great idea.

Comment: @jpmc26: you are right though about the numbers. In my head I was thinking more about the number of commenters, not the number of voters. Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep on this site to see all of the vote totals, I can only go by the final tally for each answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm hostile because you replied to what was clearly hyperbole with an argument about not *everyone* is more nervous because you're an exception, and that indicates that you don't take what I'm saying seriously. I even went on to elaborate that the point I was making was about a net increase site wide in negative emotion, which you then went on to dismiss as well in spite of evidence that the concerns have at least some fairly wide appeal. That you tried to sugar coat it didn't make this a more pleasant conversation; it just made it feel fake.

Comment: @jpmc26 _" and that indicates that you don't take what I'm saying seriously."_ - if that is what you inferred, I apologize.

Comment: I WOULD agree if there would only be that "noob"-sticker. In fact (at least in germany) if you got a "Learner"-Sticker on your car others are even more aggressive (in my experience). BUT the wording does matter here. Reminding us to be polite and friendly CAN improve SO a lot. We will have to see if this really works, but I have the hopes that reminding us that we were beginners, too could work.

Comment: @OleAlbers Why should people only be nice to new users?  Why shouldn't they be nice to users that have been around for more than a few days on that account?  Also keep in mind that the vast majority of people, in the vast majority of situations, *are* being nice, so constantly telling people who are *already* being nice, that they should be nice, is just antagonizing them and making them feel accused and targeted, when they aren't doing anything wrong.

Comment: @Servy No one is saying that "people should **only** be nice to new users", the problem is that SE is very **hostile** to newbies, making them think "should ask **anywhere** else next time", so just the ones which are able to ignore all that hostility can remain on SE. This remainder are what the SE are trying to do to fix this issue.

Comment: @Zhigalin SE is difficult to use for people that ask low quality questions and that don't take the time and effort to follow the rules and be.  It's not hostile at all, and new users that spend the time it takes to actually ask good questions have great experiences and feel very welcomed, just as people who have been around for a long time and that consistently post substandard content have poorer experiences.  That people unable or unwilling to follow the rules tend to go places that have very low standards isn't undesirable at all.

Comment: @Servy this is not a matter of quality. For example I have asked a question which got instantly dupehammed.

Comment: If I was a newbie I'd have just quit SE. Fortunately I wasn't a newbie on SE so I went to close vote chat and asked WTF and my question got reopened by others, which caused an anger explosion by the one who have closed it and a RO intervention. Not an exciting or welcoming experience at all. (that time I thought, "wow, SE is as hostile to newbies as it was 4 years ago when I have registered")

Comment: @Zhigalin A question of yours being closed as a duplicate, and you needing to explain to others why the duplicate doesn't answer your question, doesn't make SO "hostile to new people".  That you think new users are unable of reading and following the instructions given to them (to explain how the duplicate fails to answer their question) means you apparently think very little of them.  It's not that hard.

Comment: @Servy `you think new users are unable of reading and following the instructions` I don't think so, you invented it. The problem is that even if you follow the instructions the result is not guaranteed, just because someone with a dupehammer have not bothered himself to actually **read** my question. That is what I call hostility. BTW, that person with dupehammer is among others here complaining about the waving hand indicator.

Comment: @Zhigalin Your evidence that doesn't work is you providing one example of it working just fine.  That...doesn't support your position at all.  In fact it refutes it.  I hate to break it to you, but having a system in place for allowing duplicate questions to be closed as duplicates isn't hostile, nor is it hostile for someone to close a question and have it reopened shortly thereafter because others disagreed that it was a duplicate.  You appear to be defining "hostile" as "doing things that you don't like," when that's not what the word means.

Comment: @Zhigalin And what's your evidence for asserting that if you didn't go to chat the post wouldn't have been reopened?  Additionally your assertion that when someone posted inappropriate content it was immediately deal with suggests that inappropriate behavior *isn't* welcome here, and is quickly addressed (something you'll rarely find basically anywhere else on the internet with user generated content at SO's scale).

Comment: @Servy it might have, it might have not.
`You appear to be defining "hostile" as "doing things that you don't like," that's not what the word means` You know, hostility is not objective, it's subjective. I felt the hostility of SE when I first registered, I felt it again this time. The problem is not following the rules, the problem is that the rules are interpreted vaguely by those who is applying them so you need to fight every time and is is not productive, constructive or helping. Anyway, I am not going to change your mind and vice versa so let's end here before we will got moved to chat.

Comment: @Zhigalin *You* are the one asserting that your question wouldn't have been reopened if you had followed the instructions given on what to do when your question is closed.  You need to support such an assertion.  Yes, some people will disagree on whether a given post is appropriate or not.  That's okay.  Just getting rid of all of the rules and letting everyone do whatever they want because dealing with disagreements over the rules is not a viable alternative; it's *far* worse, and creates a community that ceases to create useful content.

Comment: Confused still. What if the user asked 40 questions with all negative score but none been flagged before and none been closed. Then the user is very familiar to the site though the user still has only 1 rep.

Comment: @zixuan Such a user will have been question banned by the time they've asked more than a handful of questions if they're not earning *any* reputation on any of their questions.  The only way you'll see someone with 40 questions and 1 rep is if they're suspended.

Answer (score 174):

**Noob alert! Remember to put on your kid gloves!** Seriously?

I don't like this at all. Yes, some people are new to the site. Yes, we should know that they may not understand all the rules. But no, we should not stick a big noob warning on their profile tag for everyone to see. Not only does it feel slightly passive aggressive, it automatically puts people into the mindset that the "new contributor" will not understand how the site works, or even the concepts behind the questions they are asking.

As an anecdote, I've had maybe 10 accounts here over the years, some anonymous or unregistered. This one is the one I've kept for longest. I still occasionally post anonymously for various reasons. I have noticed a troubling trend. Whenever I ask from a new account, the answers I get are often dumbed down or explain things I already know. This happens even if I am showing a clear understanding of the concepts I am discussing. If I ask the question on my main account, I notice that the answers are far more technical and *helpful*. The only possible reason for this is that people are looking at my rep and assuming I am naïve. This would be made *much worse* if people were given a big notice that I am a delicate new user...

We should not judge how new someone is by their time on the site, but only by the quality of their contributions. If someone is using the wrong tag, *that* is when you gently correct them. If someone is asking a question in the wrong place, *that* is when you point them to where they should go. Unless someone is showing that they misunderstand the site, we should treat them as *equals* who are equally competent (and who very well may be, as many people who are writing their first question have been reading Stack Exchange sites for years). The idea that we are putting a big noob alert on people's profiles is disgusting.

Comment: Until proven in contrary, I often have my doubts a low user rep is a new user to the site; being so easy creating here accounts is being heavily gamed. A new tag won´t change that.

Comment: You raise a very good point. I've noticed this behavior as well. I didn't get active in the site until well into my career, and it took about a year before people stopped talking to me like I'm a 14 y/o who's learning to program for the first time. I have less than 1k rep on SO, because I'm primarily a Java developer, and all the low-hanging fruit for that language has been harvested. But I still get some mostly useless answers in the rare cases I have to ask a question related to that language ecosystem. I think you've identified an actual problem we could be solving, but here we are.

Comment: _"Not only does it feel slightly passive aggressive, it automatically puts people into the mindset that the "new contributor" will not understand how the site works, or even the concepts behind the questions they are asking."_ Translation: It's condescending, by assuming that `newAccount == notVerySmart`.

Answer (score 121):

Ouch. Whatever made you think this is a good idea?

Well, ok, I can see how it would be appealing. But have you considered the potential downsides from labeling new users with a target marked “NOOB”?

There's a small but vocal minority of Stack Overflow users (I think it's mostly SO, or maybe it's just that 0.00001% of any other site is approximately 0) who are actively hostile to new users — refusing to answer, not making the slightest effort to help. Painting bigger targets will only make that problem worse.

And then there's a bunch of well-meaning people who go out stalking for new users to <s>hit them on the head with</s> tell them to go read this FAQ, and that FAQ, and that IAQ for good measure, and all of meta. Guys, I know you mean well, but:

1. It's ***creepy***. Sure, some of the recipients feel welcomed. But others feel overwhelmed, or worse, stalked. You probably don't hear about the third category because they generally won't come back.
2. It's rarely helpful because it's almost always some canned comment which has absolutely no bearing on whatever problem the user may be facing.

[It happened to me on TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/welcome-page-needs-more-welcoming/3772#3772) the first time I posted a question there, and I was rather creeped out. I was a veteran Stack Exchange user at the time, so I just shrugged it off — I mean, as a moderator, I'd probably seen worse comments that day — but if that had been my first contact with Stack Exchange, I would have hesitated before coming back.

Stack Exchange should not encourage any *generic* treatment of new users. People who help new users should do it *because* the user needs guidance, and provide **the guidance that the user needs**.

Instead of labeling users as “NEW!”, provide indicators that guide helpful veterans towards users in need of help. The first post review is a good one, though a user doesn't become a veteran after their first post. Automatic flags is another, but that only handles extreme cases where a sizable proportion of the needed help is helping the user off the site.

The system itself could do a much better job at providing guidance. Guidance given by an automatic system is better than posted by humans: it doesn't give the feeling that everybody's eyes are following you, and it's easier to excuse it if it's off the mark. Humans should be the second level of recourse, and should always, always give *relevant* guidance. To first posters and non-first-posters alike.

Comment: I think the issue here is throwing the FAQ at new users, not the new contributor indicator itself. I certainly agree with finding this kind of canned comment for new users somewhere between weird and creepy, but this already happens and I think should be treated as a separate issue.

Comment: .....? "refusing to answer" is not hostile.

Comment: Yes, it’s creepy. I can still remember writing my first answers, and I probably would have been in your third category. It was already bad enough having only 1 or 101 reputation clearly visible under my name.

Comment: I agree very much with this answer. This is why I've always held out against using 'canned' comments - sure, they're easier to produce, but often less directly relevant. Giving a new user *specific, on-point* advice is much more likely to make them feel 'helped' than a canned comment that looks like it was produced by a bot.

Comment: @user202729 Refusing to answer -- as opposed to not answering -- is hostile. Not answering *because they're new* is hostile.

Comment: I’m conflicted about this. On the one hand, your discussion reminds me of [a vaguely similar idea that U&L rejected](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4057/23408 "Quality-based tag for novice questions").  On the other hand, if somebody wants to “stalk” new users, all they have to do is lurk in the First Posts Review Queue.  I don’t even understand how *this* proposal (labeling new users) would make it any easier for a “stalker” to find new users than it already is.

Comment: @Scott There's a difference between having to explicitly visit a queue and getting the information passively during normal browsing.

Comment: To be frank, I've spoken with users who've said that this flag (and the banner in the answer box warning them of the dire consequences of offending this new user) has made them fearful of answering and just not bothered.

Comment: In my experience, there's a run-the-gauntlet-and-take-your-licks new user experience on every SE site. I'm a decade user, and a moderator, and it still happens to *me* if I jump onto a new site. It amazes me how many people *aren't* driven off by that. It mostly seems to be based on existing users not trusting new faces to stick around and behave well, until they have proven they will. So if existing users are *already* noticing noobs and treating them differently, I really don't see the harm in the SE software also trying to recognize them, and reminding existing users to not decapitate them.

Comment: _"Automatic flags is another, but that only handles extreme cases where a sizable proportion of the needed help is helping the user off the site."_ Hehe

Answer (score 99):

Okay - why does it *matter* if the user is a new contributor or new to a technology when they're asking a question?

I feel like this particular aspect is being ignored; it **should not matter** in the slightest if a person is new to a technology or new to a community.  This feels like it's moving the lion's share of the onus of participation etiquette from the new participant to the veterans.

I get it - some veterans can be jerks.  We don't deal with them any differently here since we're not changing how we flag; we simply add another chiding warning to the veterans who engage with these users.

I want a satisfactory answer as to why it **matters** that a user gets labeled as such.  Once that's answered, *then* this marker could be justified.

Right now I'm not seeing it.

This feature may wind up having a more chilling effect with engagement as opposed to just-in-time guidance for a new user to help them understand what's going on with the interaction of their question.

Comment: I've never been in an organization where expectations didn't increase with membership time: school, business, the military, even personal relationships. If you expected the same from a first date that you do from a marriage of ten years I don't see a second date ever coming. The Marines spend at least 4 months on-boarding and when you're done you're still a "boot" (newbie).

Comment: @TemporalWolf:  Sure, but Stack Exchange communities are none of those.  Sure, some sites have lots of rules, but the expectation has largely stayed the same:  ask a clear, concise and on-topic question, complete with any details that would enable anyone else to help you with your problem.  The fact that someone is new to a topic or a community is so irrelevant that it's [edited out of Stack Overflow questions as ***noise***.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/1079354)

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but it almost certainly does. I can't find it now, but someone - Jon maybe - made the point recently that we're pretty good at providing feedback when someone's doing poorly, but not so good at it when they're *improving*. Upvotes vs downvote *and* close *and* comments. Statistically, someone's very first post is likely to be terrible... But if they stick around, their next post will be considerably better, and the next one better yet, and so on - the trick is to get 'em past that hump where they're very bad at this but they've learned something and can do better.

Comment: I'm not going to deny that any beginner questions are awful or that asking questions is  a hard problem @Shog9, since both of those statements are independently and verifiable of their own volition.  What I'm *highly* leery of is the fact that a new system feature is being built to emphasize the kind of noise we keep out of our questions.  Years of removing, "I am new to..." has demonstrated to me that it's not germane to the problem or the question at hand.  What value are you looking to get out of a feature that does this?  What problem is this really attempting to solve?

Comment: @Shog9 Statistically we're much better at providing positive feedback than negative feedback, just look at how many more upvotes are cast than downvotes.  Jon's post was saying that statistically people are more likely to come back when they get lots of comments, regardless of what the comments say, than if they get none, and that people that got lots of downvotes were less likely to come back than those that didn't, but that it was a much smaller effect than other factors, such as comments.

Comment: We're *great* at providing positive feedback, @Servy (albeit served up as intermittent reinforcement), but that's not what I'm talking about. Tell me if you've seen this: user posts terrible question - it's missing details, code is excessively long and isn't formatted, title contains no useful information whatsoever. Then they edit it to include missing details, maybe format the code. Question is still very much not good... But they've improved it a lot. To get them to improve it *further*, they need some reinforcement - but the question still sucks, so they don't get it.

Comment: @Shog9 Sure, that's true enough.  The question is how to give them feedback that they've made it better, while still making sure everyone else can still see that the question isn't actually good, because everyone other than the author (usually) just wants to know if it's good or not, not whether it's better or worse than it used to be.

Comment: Maybe I'm off base here, but it seems the answer to *why* is that SE is turning their focus away from producing and maintaining quality Q&A and towards making it a friendly and inclusive environment. Probably the ultimate goal is to increase retention so users will contribute more and improve the Q&A. Certainly, though, the *put on your kid gloves* message won't immediately impact the quality of Q&A in a positive way, so this is absolutely a user-focused change, not content-focused.

Comment: @Shog9  Sorry, you're leaving out the fate of 98% of new users, and only counting the ultimate success of 2% of users, and blaming current users for the fate of those that never moved on.   Show me the stats; show me how many users ask one question, maybe four in one day, and then disappear, and come back one week later, create a new account, ask the homework questions they put off doing, say five questions in 3 hours, then the account ends.  Then before the final exam, or during their final *take home exam*, create yet another account and ask away, as they are yet again, a new contributor.

Comment: There are lots of them, @amWhy. What's your point?

Comment: Show me why in the heck we should parade a "New Contributor" banner attached to the eighth username for the eighth and newest account of one chronic new-account-creator gaming the system?  New Contributors are going to be just as suspect as "member since today" new users.  This is NOT FIXING what NEEDS to be fixed.  Go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 80):

**Will new users also see this mini-banner on their *own* posts?**

I could imagine someone being slightly perturbed by seeing a "welcome to the site" type comment when they've been around for 6 days or so. They might think *"how do they know I'm new? have they been stalking my profile to check the dates of all my posts?!"* (This was one of the reasons cited on at least one SE site for banning "welcome to the site" comments unless they have some other useful content - it could be seen as stalkerish.)

**I would suggest replacing the "be nice" with a reminder that this user may not know community norms.**

As other people here have pointed out, we're meant to be nice to *everyone*, not just new users. It seems redundant, and worse than that, it could give the impression that the CoC is more lax when talking to more experienced users. How about something like:

> Dan is a new contributor. Remember that they may not be aware of Stack Exchange policies and norms, so please be patient when explaining to them.

Presumably the main aim here is to replace comments like "we use *this* tag for questions about X, not *that* one - you should know this, because it's all clearly explained in this meta post" with comments more like "hey, just to let you know, on this site we use *this* tag instead of *that* one for questions about X - if you want to read more about why, here's a link to the explanation on our 'meta' discussion site". Not really to replace rude comments with CoC-compliant ones, because that's a more general effort and not specific to new users.

Comment: The first part of this has now been addressed by Shog [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator/314297#comment1029901_314294), but I'll leave it in my answer because it still raises a potential issue of interest.

Comment: Yes, *please* rephrase the popup text.  The purpose of the "new user" reminder should be to encourage *teaching* them the way to use the site, not *excusing* policy violations because they don't know any better.  Telling us the "be nice" is vague enough to imply either message.

Comment: @BJMyers Which is awfully funny, since the CoC was written in part *because* people thought "be nice" is too vague.

Comment: I think also important is: see new users this on the posts of other new users?

Comment: Hey, someone told me "welcome to the site" on a site that I'd been an active participant on for over five years.  It's come to just mean "I'm about to say something condescending".

Answer (score 72):

## Good UI design does not  overwhelm users with redundant information.

Repeating that new user status three times on a single page is a tad redundant.
None of the regular contributors are completely illiterate, once is probably enough.

## Good UI design does not overwhelm users with redundant information.

You have a nice and shiny new code of conduct, you don't have to link there twice on a single page.

## Good UI design does not overwhelm users with redundant information.

Did I mention yet that repeating yourself multiple times is annoying?

---

Just to illustrate what shows when I want to make a comment:

[image: What happens when I want to comment]

Answer (score 70):

This feature is rude and unwelcoming.

You're not singling out behaviors that need to change. You're dropping a blanket accusation of poor behavior on *everyone*. The very idea that everyone needs this warning is implicitly accusatory.

Even worse, **this change violates one of SO's core tenets: that it's the *content* that matters, not who writes it.** The newness of the user is completely irrelevant. Either the user made a quality post and followed our rules and norms or they didn't. The result should be the same either way: downvote, closure, deletion if bad, upvote if good, or no action if not good enough to warrant an upvote. Possibly a comment explaining the problems or requesting improvements. This feature sends the message to all users that "new" users should be treated differently, and they should not. They should be held to the same standard. Period.

Because of this, it also means you're attaching a new stigma to new users that SO has fairly successfully avoided since its founding. You're implying that new users are *incapable* of writing good posts. This only undermines your own efforts to be welcoming. I have never subscribed to the notion that our problem questions are primarily due to users being new or unfamiliar with the site; the primary cause behind bad posts is a lack of effort. Bad posts come from an unwillingness to spend the time required to obtain some level of understanding about the nature of the problem they're facing or to clearly present that understanding. This is completely unrelated to the newness of the user. This new feature instead wrongly implies a *causation* of newness, rather than the mere possible correlation. Our moderation efforts tend to drive users unwilling to spend that effort away, at least somewhat, so it's not surprising that we'd see a correlation without a causation.

Comment: How does flagging someone as new count as "dropping a blanket accusation"? The flag presents information, it doesn't accuse anyone of anything.

Comment: @BryanOakley Because without making the assumption that a majority of SO users are behaving improperly, it doesn't make any sense to show it to everyone. I explicitly said that the accusation is *implicit*.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree it makes the assumption that a _majority_ of users are behaving improperly, but I do think that there are a large number of people on this site who behave improperly. If that wasn't the case, SO wouldn't be gaining a reputation of being hostile to new users.

Comment: @BryanOakley Any community that moderates its content is going to have a reputation of being hostile among people who don't meet the quality standard. (And the steady stream of garbage posts is plenty of evidence that there is a large group of people falling in that category.) Such a reputation is meaningless for determining causes and a course of action forward.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ? Looks like maybe was supposed to be on another answer?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. The edit and **its** explanation are both correct but **it's** super trivial, and superficial. It didn't substantially improve anything.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh. Thought you were replying to a comment. I didn't even see the edit comment. =) I don't mind minor corrections of my typos; in fact, I appreciate them. Not completely sure about your thoughts on the message, though; maybe you're right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Peter is a top editor across the network and when he does something this is usually for a good reason. I think in this case polishing the minor typo looked worthy to him because it's one of the top voted answers in the announcement advertised via [tag:featured] tag to whole SE network (as of now it has over 11K views). Worth mentioning that this post will attract attention even after advertising is over because it is the primary source of knowledge for a new, highly visible and quite controversial site feature

Comment: @gnat removing an apostrophe is a trivial edit. And was explaining the difference in meaning between "it's" and "its" absolutely necessary? But, let's leave it at that. I really wanted Peter Mortensen to think twice before fixing a post because there's a missing comma.

Comment: @Mari-LouA in my previous comment I explained why I think in this case even trivial edits are okay. As for explanation (in the [tag:edit-summary] which is intended for stuff like that), I don't understand why you seem to insist that it must be absolutely necessary. I find it useful both for post authors and for future editors, and since it isn't visible to readers there are no negative effects at all and that suffices to me

Comment: @Mari-LouA I actually disagree with you on performing the edit. I typo quite often, and it annoys me when I come back 5 months later and see it. xD So I do appreciate fixes to grammar and mechanics, no matter how small. I've definitely argued in the past that "minor" edits should be encouraged (though the site probably needs to be adjusted to not bump the posts). I can see how the edit comment comes off as condescending, though. If I'd just seen it on my own without it being pointed out first, I might have taken it rather poorly.

Answer (score 66):

Just curious what the *veteran contributor* indicator is going to look like and how SE will word the warning to be nice and respectful to them for taking their time to help you learn how to use the site and provide answers for free by actually following the instructions/advice left in the comments instead of complaining about it and calling people names and posting *@downvoter explain!*

Let me suggest some copy:

[image]

Maybe reinforce it with *Always remember they are trying to help you!* somewhere in all bold flashing rainbow colors or something. :-)

Comment: I would imagine most _veteran contributors_ do this out of the joy of helping people, and don't need to be thanked for taking their time to help someone for free. For me, at least, knowing I helped someone is the only reward I need.

Comment: My initial thought was that the notice will say that this is a veteran user who should know better by now, so you should feel free to downvote, vote to close, or flag if they aren’t following the guidelines. Maybe that’s not the state of mind the “new contributor” notice was intended to put me in though. *grimace*

Comment: @BryanOakley Me, too, 100%. That's exactly why it's so galling to be treated as if I'm an unhelpful BOFH.

Comment: Would be more useful if this is displayed in the comment section.

Answer (score 60):

I think that some of these, particularly the notification in the answer box, is too intrusive. The tag on the user's infobox is livable. The tag on the comment box is odd, but maybe acceptable. But the tag on the answer box is too much.

While one could argue that the tone of comments may need to vary from user to user, the tone of *answers* does not. When posting the answer, you aren't posting it for "a new user". You're not talking to the user; you're talking about the user's *question*. So there's no reason to have a giant box that says "NEW USER!!!" sitting there.

There is also some danger that experienced users may use this as a reason to ignore such questions and simply not provide answers to any user with this tag in the answer box.

Comment: The tag on the comment box only appears when you hover over the tag on the userrs infobox.

Comment: Don't forget the "clearly you experienced lot can't be trusted to act like decent human beings without being constantly reminded that THIS POOR NOOB IS NEW HERE WATCH OUT AND READ THE CODE OF CONDUCT GUYS" theme. So inclusive.

Comment: Not just "new user!!" but also a direct link to the code of conduct so people can make complaints about you

Comment: Agreed. I have solved this with a user style of `#post-editor .new-contributor-indicator, form[id^="add-comment-"] .new-contributor-indicator { display: none; }` applying to the SO and SE domains. It leaves the notice under user cards but does not show it on input boxes.

Answer (score 58):

I understand your reasoning for doing this, but do not like the implementation. I also wonder if you have considered the side effects. After some time to reflect, I do not think this is a good idea in the present state.

First off, the warning banner is kind of insulting.

> [User278094](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278094) is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

With that, you are automatically assuming that us "more experienced users" will not be nice to new users, and need a reminder to do so. In my opinion, that little bit and the link to the CoC is completely unnecessary. If we do not already know to be nice **to everyone** and follow the CoC, a banner is not going to help.

Something like this would convey your intended message without coming across as condescending or belittling to us "more experienced users".

> [User278094](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278094) is a new contributor. Take a bit of extra time to show them the ropes.

---

You are *creating* a class of users. Yes, we need to treat new users with a little more grace, help them along, and all the other little things that need to be learned to succeed on SE. But sticking a "New" label on them does not necessarily help anything.
I'm going to venture a guess and say that it will hurt their chances of getting their question answered. New users can't UV. New users are *much* more unlikely to accept your answer.
You take those two points and then stick a warning on every new post reminding people of that and it does not help the answer rate.

---

No matter how "nice" and "welcoming" everyone on SE is to new users, we still do have the same problem with new users. They do not know how our sites work, and in many cases they do not care. They just want their question answered.
This new banner *may* help some but it is coming at the problem from the wrong end.

It's like a "dangerous intersection" sign. It is reminding the drivers that something is ahead, but really the intersection should just be fixed.

Sure, we can try everything to make all the existing and established SE users be extra specially nice to new users, but we still need to fix the low-quality posts from the new users.

Comment: Along with reducing the answer rate, I think it will also reduce the chances of getting a helpful comment, because I've learned that new users are much more likely than experienced users to respond negatively to feedback.

Comment: I agree with this notice, the current signs look more like ads to the CoC than anything else. However, “show them the ropes” is something I cannot understand. I know each of the words but have no idea (without Google…) what [the idiom means](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/show+the+ropes). Please take into account that many users don’t have English as their native language.

Comment: I'd go with the analogy of a "Bad road surface" sign, since that's really just a lazy way of not-fixing the road but pulling your hands off instead, otherwise great analogy and good observations about the UV and accepts from new users. I answer in a relatively small tag for a university-paid programming language, so each semester there are new student coming here. Accepts are a rare sight, and every now and then OPs even delete their question when they get their answer out of fear of being discovered by the teacher.

Answer (score 49):

Nobody reads the mumbo-jumbo when signing up for a community. Nobody reads the pinned FAQ topics on top of a forum. Nobody reads the tour. Nobody previews their question before posting it. Nobody lurks for a while to get the *mores* of a community before posting something by themselves. And nobody seems to remember that Stack Overflow was meant to build a library of canonical questions that help many programmers.

Face it; 90% of questions are about debugging someone's code, and 90% of those questions either don't contain enough code to properly reproduce the issue or don't contain enough explanation to properly answer the question, making it irrelevant for later visitors and uninteresting for existing answerers. Please don't call people who dump their partial non-compiling code "contributors".

Question askers just want their damn code fixed, and right now at that, and answerers of such questions just want to get a lot of reputation so they can show off their profile to their potential employers.

I'm not saying I want to be able to say *"Hey asshole, your question sucks, learn to debug!"* under a question, or *"Dude, can you at least type some comments in this code dump of an answer?"*. I'm saying that this indicator feels like a giant slap in the face as if all of us do this so frequently, and that this makes me feel even more like Stack Overflow *just* wants to retain more users on their platform and doesn't care anymore about what those users do there, as long as they generate pageviews, all under a thin veil of "please be nice to each other".

Comment: Keep in mind that a high rep users generate far less ad revenue per page view; users are shown far fewer ads whenever they hit that privilege at...whatever rep it's at.  So maximizing page views from *low* rep users generates more money.  (In the short term.  Of course, pushing away experienced users means lower quality, which means lower views in the long term when people learn that SO doesn't actually have good answers anymore.)

Comment: This post nicely illustrates a harmful mindset that I've encountered a lot on SO. By the time _I_ ask a question, I usually (dumb oversights happen) have read the doc, the manual, searched the web, etc. I'm still treated as somebody who "just wants their damn code fixed" and receive junk responses as a result -- by people who clearly haven't read the question, or haven't tried to understand it at all. But, alas, that won't be fixed by the "new contributor" indicator. Maybe a similar indicator for "this person has asked good questions before, don't write the post off immediately". ;)

Comment: I read the tour and the FAQ back when I joined.

Comment: @Raphael there is no "harmful mindset" illustrated by my post. Writing a good question is _hard_, despite the fact questions get asked every second. What _you_ may consider a clear, understandable, answerable question can others consider unclear for a plethora of reasons. Sure, there are people who're just in it for the rants, but assume most seasoned people are here to help - with clear, answerable, unique problems. Which are rare.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sure, no question is perfect; I usually revise mine multiple times in response to helpful comments. Still, it would be nice if everybody bothered to fully read the question before commenting. I mean cases where the answer to their reflexive questions are _literally_ in the question body. Or they propose things that are explicitly stated as already tried. Or make assumptions clearly contradicting the question. (FWIW, I'll readily admit that I'm guilty of this myself on [cs.SE]; you get trigger happy after closing the first few hundred of same-form questions! Not ideal, though.)

Answer (score 48):

For those that don't want to see this notification / banner, add the following rule to your adblocker:

```
##.new-contributor-indicator
```

Or using a userstyles plugin:

```css
.new-contributor-indicator{
    display:none;
}
```

Or a userscript:

```js
$('<style type="text/css">.new-contributor-indicator {display: none;}</style>')
    .appendTo($('head'));
```

This should block the indicator from showing up on the answer field, and on the user information under the question.

Answer (score 41):

<s>Three</s> Two suggested improvements:

**For the experienced users:** change "be sure to check out our Code of Conduct" to "remember to follow our Code of Conduct" or similar.  "Check out" sounds like "hey, we have this thing you might not have seen and you should take a look", but we expect experienced users to have already done that.  A *reminder* is gentler and still gets the point across.

**For editors:** you've covered comments and answers; it would be nice to add some edit guidance too, specifically for the edit reason.  (Fill it in!  Tell people *why* you made a change and not just *what* you changed.)

<s>**For moderators:** when anything on the page is flagged (the question, answers, comments), it'd be helpful to us to know what the person being flagged saw, i.e. that this user's new-user status was visible.  While we take rudeness seriously wherever we see it, I expect that rudeness to new users would prompt a stronger reaction, like contacting the user sooner.</s> -- Comments convinced me that this shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: I agree with "Remember" or "Remember to follow" in place of "Check out" — people should already have checked it out and just need reminding to follow it.  The URL allows them to check it out if it is new(s) to them.

Comment: I agree with the first two, not necessarily the third. Can't see why it should make a difference for moderators handling flags.

Comment: @Randal'Thor handling the flag should be the same either way, but when there are patterns, like when somebody manages to hit the too-many-rude-comments alert, it feels like it would be helpful to know if he *also* ignored the in-your-face guidance.  I can see it affecting the mod message I send.

Comment: Why should rudeness to new users prompt a stronger reaction? As an established user, I wouldn't want rudeness towards me to be ignored or handled less seriously than towards new people just because they're new.

Comment: @Undo hmm, maybe you're right.  thanks.  (Also Rand.)  Edited.

Answer (score 40):

I have a question regarding this: **What will the new user see when they are posting for the first time?**

If new users don't get any additional guidance from what they've already been getting, then looks like we've fixed only one side of the problem. There are two great suggestions here, which would help a bit:

- [New users need better awareness of what is expected of them when they ask their first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903/311398)
- [New users need better awareness of what is expected of them when they answer their first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285924/311398)

I get it that we should tackle problems one at a time. Given that we've now fixed one side, can we fix the other side too?

Comment: @Bh - the wizard will help them soon - which is coming down the pipeline in september.

Comment: @JonH, Yup, waiting for that. You can notice that it's got 450+ upvotes, because everyone is waiting for that instead of these minor changes... :)

Comment: My point was you know the answer - why are you re-asking what you already know?

Comment: There are two parts here (questions and answers), the wizard answers half of the first one.

Comment: FWIW, the extra bit of the signature block will show up to the post's owner too - so it ain't like we're putting some secret mark on their backs. Also... This isn't just for questions; it's possible to end up in a scenario where both the asker and answerer are "new users" and see complementary instructions when interacting...

Comment: "The established users now know that a certain poster is a new user", how is that new? I see their reputation being 1 (or even <100) and I know they are new users.

Comment: @Camilo Exactly! That's the pointless part about the new feature mentioned in the question which we all are debating about, you can totally (and should) add that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 39):

This doesn't seem very helpful to me. I am glad that we have the first posts review queue, but I don't feel convinced that a new contributor indicator shown to all users will help with on-boarding new users.

New users, like any other users, come here to get answers to their questions, or to answer other people's questions. Having a different attitude towards their posts can only improve their experience to a limited extent.

For example, a user who posts an off-topic or overly broad question is likely to have a frustrating experience. The only way I can see of really avoiding that would be to get rid of the site mechanisms for shutting down or altering these kinds of questions—and doing that is obviously impractical. As long as  these mechanisms exist, they will be obstacles to getting an answer. Being told that your question is "on hold" instead of "closed" might feel a bit less like a slap in the face, but it's still not a positive experience. I think the same goes for comments: even though it might be more upsetting to get a snarky comment than to get a sincere, earnest suggestion about how to improve your question, I don't think either really feels great. Nor does being ignored.

Helping new users to make better posts from the start seems like a more promising avenue of improvement to me: an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure. That's why I've been looking forward to the new ask wizard (of course, it remains to be seen how effective that can be).

As Robert Harvey said in the [top-voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903/306255) to the 2016 "[Let's Plan the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889)" question:

> **New users need better awareness of what is expected of them when they ask their first question.** [...] **The best off-topic question is the one that is never asked.** Allowing sites to run off the rails by providing the lowest possible friction to ask off-topic questions and then saddling the community with cleaning up those questions... well, that's not what most of us signed up for, nor is it the best use of our time. *It is probably the least-friendly way to welcome new users.*
>
> Most of the professionals who are here come here to contribute and to help others, not to spend all of their time sweeping the floor.

A "new contributor" indicator doesn't seem to do anything to alleviate that problem.

#### Responses to specific things

> We hope folks will try to explain the why in addition to
>   the what or how when you show new folks the ropes of using our system,
>   and try to make them feel like it's within their immediate capability
>   to be successful here. Experienced contributors don't need to know
>   that their formatting looks good when you mention that they forgot to
>   include a version number, but new contributors really appreciate that
>   encouragement.

I don't think everybody responds well to praise, and it's somewhat difficult to use well. The "sandwich method" of criticism and similar strategies can come across as condescending. So I'm skeptical of the idea that we ought to encourage people to give more praise to new users than to experienced contributors (or that we should praise new users' ability to use site functions, even if that ability would be unremarkable for an established user).

> Flag comments that are unfriendly or simply unhelpful. New users can do this now on posts that they own, but let's show people that we're serious about investing as much in them as they do in us. Snark sets a bad impression, but snark vanishing quickly sets a much better one.

This is something that people should do for any post. I'm confused by the implication that users who would otherwise neglect to flag unfriendly or unhelpful comments will be motivated to do so by a new user indicator. I don't feel like this matches my own experience of using the flag system.

> Don't add to 'pile on' scenarios of any kind; let moderators know if something needs immediate attention.

As with the previous, pile-ons are bad on any kind of post. They may be more a problem with new users' posts because new users are more likely to post questions or answers that have obvious problems, which I think is one of the things that causes people to pile on with critical comments or downvotes. Moderators can delete long comment chains, I guess, but I feel like they're usually not quick enough to prevent the original poster from noticing the hostile atmosphere, so I don't see this as a full solution to the problem.

> Help new users by editing their posts, and leaving them a comment explaining how your edit improved things.

Editing a new user's post is always a bit dangerous, since inevitably some people (including people who write useful, thoughful questions) will be upset, or at the worse case, blow up, about someone else "putting words into their mouths". (And sometimes these kinds of complaints are clearly justified: I've certainly seen some edits that have changed the meaning of questions.) It's hard for users to make sure that their edit will be received well, even if they leave a comment trying to explain the reasons for the edit.

Furthermore, many posts have problems that cannot/should not be fixed by another user's edits.

I agree with BJ Myers' suggestion of having the system show a special message to new users the first time their post is edited: this would ensure that they receive some information about the Stack Exchange philosophy of editing at an appropriate time.

> Don't forget to up-vote stuff that you feel has value. It's strange when a question gets *three plus* answers, yet not a single vote. There's no obligation, of course, but the indicator is a helpful reminder.

Different people might experience the site differently, but for me, getting three answers and no upvotes feels way better than getting three upvotes and no answer to my question. Upvotes on questions are a nice extra, I guess, but the main thing people are looking for when they post a question here is answers, not fake internet points.

It doesn't seem that strange to me that a question might get answers but no upvotes. Most users don't upvote every on-topic question on the site, and the value of upvotes as indicators of the most useful questions would be lost if people used them this way. But every on-topic question certainly ought to be answered, and it's a good thing if people do post answers even to mediocre or somewhat boring questions (much better than the alternative scenarios of these questions being ignored or closed).

For answers, the idea that people need to be "reminded" to vote doesn't really make sense to me. Voting on answers is very intuitive, and I don't think people should apply different standards to answers by  veterans vs. newbies.

Comment: Voting is not at all intuitive. For newbies, it is impossible.

Answer (score 36):

Aren't you forgetting the big ideals of providing help, regardless of who posted the question?

You always declined feature requests for the possibility to ignore specific users, with blabla about building a database of knowledge regardless of who asked the question, and now you are branding a whole group of users?

If you are allowed to mark users, also give users the possibility to mark users they want to recognize.

Comment: So much this. SO has abandoned the very notion of fair treatment in favor of trying to produce equal outcomes.

Comment: This is about the interaction in comments, not whether or how you answer.

Comment: @Raphael Comments are also a way to help people. But anyway this banner is not only displayed below the name, in the comment box but also in the answer box, so pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 30):

So, whom this has been added for? I mean, people can clearly see new members reputation. And this information is enough.

This update just added a lot of garbage on the screen, that only distracts attention from the question itself.

Comment: The reputation number alone doesn't tell the whole story. If their rep is 1, is that because they are brand new, or because they've asked 100 questions and had a mix of up-votes and down-votes that resulted in a total rep of 1.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've never seen ppl with 100 questions and 1 rep (:

Comment: @BryanOakley Apart from being impossibly rare, if a user has asked 100 questions and still only has a rep of 1 then they would seem to be doing something wrong and probably need to be treated as a "New contributor"!

Comment: @MrWhite: Maybe, maybe not. Don't focus on the number 100. This answer says the indicator isn't adding new information, the point I was trying to make is that I think it does.

Comment: @BryanOakley Upvotes give 2.5x more reputation than downvotes, and downvotes when a user has 1 reputation don't remove *anything*.  A user needs to be getting basically 100% downvotes to stay at 1 rep for more than a few questions, and after a few questions of 100% downvotes, they'll get question banned, rendering the whole point moot.  So the only possible way to have more than a few questions *necessitates* earning some amount of reputation.

Comment: @Servy: _"downvotes when a user has 1 reputation don't remove anything."_ - I disagree. downvotes don't remove _reputation_, but they serve to discourage new users. That's more important that made-up points. We've got to stop down-voting new users into oblivion the first time they step foot into this site.

Comment: People seem to be nitpicking my choice of 100 and 1 rather than looking at the meaning behind my comment. Instead of 100 and 1, choose 5 and 2. The point being, a low rep might mean a new user and it might mean something else. This notice clarifies that by adding more information. I do not see additional information as a bad thing.

Comment: @BryanOakley The point there was that it's basically impossible to have a user with 1 reputation that has lots of contributions.  It's not to say that downvoting a user with one rep is pointless.  Obviously it's still useful feedback on the quality of the post, and so it's very important that people cast the vote, even though it results in no change in reputation.  Your assertion that we should be not downvoting bad posts, just because the author is new, is contrary to the guidelines that you should be voting on post content, not the author of a post.  Voting based on the author is vote fraud.

Comment: @Servy: _"Your assertion that we should be not downvoting bad posts,"_ - where did I make that assertion? I've never claimed any such thing. Again, don't focus on the 1 or the 100. The point is, this notice gives us more information that will help us do a better job.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, it's technically possible for a user to have very little rep and not be new.  It's also possible for an account to be brand new and for the user to not be new.  Both methods have inaccuracies.  But both are still good approximations.  This isn't a particularly better approximation.  Adding a whole bunch of redundant and useless information is very much a bad thing.  The whole premise of SO is having a high signal to noise ratio.  Adding a ton of noise isn't useful.

Comment: @Servy: I guess the difference is, I see this notice as signal, you see it as noise <shrug>

Comment: @BryanOakley You specifically said that we need to stop downvoting new users.  "We've got to stop down-voting new users into oblivion the first time they step foot into this site"

Comment: @BryanOakley And I demonstrated that your assertion that it's more informative than reputation isn't true.  So you're just asserting that it's useful to repeat the same exact information three times, which itself is a repetition of something already there, with no real basis for that.  It's irrelevant, and even if you want to see that irrelevant information, it's been there since day one.  Repeating it 3 more times isn't adding signal.

Comment: Ok, I can see how you might interpret that different than I intended. I do think we should not downvote users _immediately_. This notice gives us a reason to take a pause and ask ourselves if we can do better to help this person than to just downvote and move on. If a new user posts a lousy question and is unable to improve it, it needs to be downvoted appropriately. What I don't like is that sometimes a question will be downvoted to -5 more more before the poor user even has a chance to click the edit button.

Comment: @BryanOakley It's important to provide feedback that's accurate and *swift*.  Waiting a while to provide feedback on the quality of a post isn't helpful.  The sooner you provide feedback the sooner that feedback can be acted on, both by the author, and other readers.  One of the primary purposes of votes is to allow other users to have an idea of the communities perception of the quality of a post.  By not voting, you're depriving them of that feedback.

Comment: @Servy: it's important to provide _useful_ feedback that's accurate and swift. I would argue that multiple immediate downvotes without comments aren't particularly useful. Downvotes are difficult to overcome, adding a hurdle for a new user to get benefit out of this site. Seeing a reminder may help some of us choose to go the extra mile for a brand new user.

Comment: Note: I don't recommend always doing nothing instead of downvoting. I'm saying that for new users, we should pause for a moment and ask ourselves if we can contribute something more useful than just a negative vote. Sometimes the negative vote is appropriate, and sometimes a friendly comment is the better choice, and sometimes both is in order.

Comment: @BryanOakley Once again, you are not forced to choose between downvoting and commenting.  You're continually asserting a false dichotomy that downvotes means not commenting.  Downvotes are *very* useful.  They're a signal to everyone that a post isn't useful.  It's great to not have to waste one's time looking at a bad post, thanks to other community members that have taken the time to indicate that the post is problematic.  Again, your indication that we shouldn't be voting based on the quality of the content, but instead on the user, is strictly *against the rules*.  It's called vote fraud.

Comment: _"Once again, you are not forced to choose between downvoting and commenting. "_ Yes, I know. I think this notice works well as a reminder to take a breath and question ourselves before just downvoting and moving on.

Comment: _"You're continually asserting a false dichotomy that downvotes means not commenting."_ - if that is how my comments are perceived, I apologize. That was never my intention.

Comment: _"Again, your indication that we shouldn't be voting based on the quality of the content, but instead on the user, is strictly against the rules. It's called vote fraud."_  - no offense, but you're being silly. Choosing to offer help in addition to or instead of downvoting isn't vote fraud. It's called _helping_.

Comment: @BryanOakley But that's not what you said you were doing.  If you said you were commenting more on new user's posts, then that would be an accurate statement.  You said you were voting differently on new users posts.  That's strictly against the rules.  And again, I never said anything about not commenting on posts.  By all means, comment away.  You're the only one who's said that downvoting a post means you can't comment on it, not me.  Your choice to vote on the newness of the user instead of the post content isn't helping.  Providing accurate feedback on post quality is called helping.

Comment: @Servy: _" You're the only one who's said that downvoting a post means you can't comment on it"_ - I've never made any such claim. While I do think that downvotes are sometimes valid without comments, I think we do new users a disservice by downvoting without commenting. I like this feature because it's a little extra reminder that I should not only comment, but maybe take a few extra moments to write a polite and helpful comment.

Comment: @BryanOakley You claimed that you like to vote differently based on how new the author of a post is, I said that you should vote based on the content, not the author of the post, and you responded by saying that voting based on the quality of the post, instead of the author's age, isn't being helpful, and that you're the one being helpful by voting on the author instead of the content, which is simply absurd.  Why do you post comments that aren't polite and helpful for users that aren't new?  Why do you think it's okay to be rude and unhelpful to other users?

Comment: @Servy: _"Why do you post comments that aren't polite and helpful for users that aren't new?"_ . Simple. I don't. I almost always try to provide helpful and polite answers. Sometimes, due to my human nature, I will downvote and move on without giving much actual thought because bad questions are discouraging. Knowing that someone is new, and knowing that SO has a real problem with being hostile to newbies, I think this notices serves nicely to remind me that this person deserves a little extra help the first time or two that they ask a question.

Answer (score 29):

Being flagged as a "New contributor" on one site when they are already an *experienced contributor* on other sites in the SE network seems a bit silly. I might treat a brand new user to the *SE network* a bit differently as they may not know their way around, but if a user already has 30K rep on another site then I really don't want to be wearing my kid gloves and start explaining the basics (which could also come across as rather condescending).

But I also don't see what this provides that the existing rep score doesn't (as others have already mentioned)?

Comment: When I posted my first answer on this site I had +30k  rep on another site, and someone commented with a link on how to edit my answer...

Answer (score 28):

#### This is just another small step into the general wrong direction.

If the purported objectives of Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) were taken seriously, such an indicator wouldn't exist. If you really want to build a useful library of knowledge in a Q&A format, there's only one thing you should care about: Quality of the content.

Rude behavior like targeting someone personally, ridiculing someone, etc. shouldn't be accepted and isn't accepted by the communities. Telling people what they did wrong, that their content doesn't meet quality requirements, or perhaps that refusing to admit errors or  improve content is *stupid*, should by all means be accepted and encouraged.

Of course, we see more and more that it isn't. I've already had my (high rep) Stack Overflow account deleted for reasons along these lines. From time to time, you read about high rep users requesting deletion or just leaving silently and my guess is more and more will follow. As far as I'm concerned, it's (especially in the case of Stack Overflow) because I don't believe in the goal of building this useful library any more. It much more feels like the goal is to get clicks over clicks - both from new users and from users that somehow get addicted to reputation score, no matter how bad the content quality gets.

Please rethink this whole strategy. Regarding this "new contributor" indicator, the problem isn't that experienced users don't pamper the newcomers enough. The problem is that many newcomers don't take the time to learn what's expected. In **some** cases, the problem might be mitigated by finding better ways to present the expectations to the new users. In **most** cases, nothing will work because *they just don't care*. Well, one thing will still work: Tell them what's bad about their posts (not *rudely*, but *clearly and directly*), downvote if appropriate, and vote to close if appropriate. Someone feeling unwelcome after these reactions is very unlikely to ever make good contributions - so, why care?

Answer (score 27):

I appreciate that you try to be very welcoming to new users, but almost all of what we are supposed to do, we should do anyway, shouldn't we?

- Be nice
- Behave according to the CoC
- Flag useless comments
- Alert moderators if necessary

The only things new are:

1. Edit their posts and better explain why. That's a good reminder, although that should be done already (via edit comment). But an extra comment welcoming them and explaining it a bit more is fine.
2. Voting. If it has value - yes. But why especially with new members - we should vote on the content, not the person. So I'm not sure this is really necessary. Maybe rather write a comment explaining the voting - but what if it's a DV? Even in this case?

Comment: 'Should', and 'actively do' tend to have wildly inconsistent intersections, but yes, it's a valid point. It's there as a reminder. And you are voting on the content, it's just a reminder not to _forget_, because it's especially critical in the process of a new user figuring out if they navigated the process correctly (for the first few times, at least). Explaining  votes, and voting itself, is _always_ optional. Again, it's just nice to have a reminder at times.

Comment: comments on editorial changes are always a good idea.  but comments on downvotes are even more important -- even for non-new users.  if something is being done in an ineffective or wrong way, it's really important to know why, or the problem may never be remedied.

Comment: "Sorry to welcome you to our site with a downvote, but [...]" was a comment I saw recently (& intend to pinch). What seems perfectly friendly for a user accustomed to site norms might come across differently for one who isn't. Moreover new users often benefit from guidance as to what they're supposed to do next in response to criticism.

Answer (score 27):

I simply think: it is **too** much.

I actually like the notification for in the "user xyz asked" place. I find it a helpful reminder.

Why? Because that reminder is visually close to the comment section. And that is where most of the "harm" happens.

But at least for me on SO, I **almost never** saw an **answer** being rude, or even overly aggressive/snappy.

I therefore think: that **second** reminder in the answer section is absolutely pointless. Even when there are already multiple answers, people answering the question started reading from the top. They *saw* that this is a new user already.

If you think you have to repeatedly push this information into our faces, well, I disagree: the (assumed) 1% of nasty answers does not justify that second indicator in my eyes.

Other answers with many upvotes already suggest that people aren't too happy about the indicator at all. That part is subjective, and open for debate. If it helps to drive down nasty/snappy comments: fine with me.

But as explained: answers aren't comments, and repeating the indication is a waste of screen spaces, furthermore sending a "we do not trust you" message between the lines to your experienced users.

And honestly: when people write answers, they hope for upvotes and accepts. That alone is a much better motivation to be *overly* kind anyway.

Edit: regarding the indicator shown when writing comments, well. I can see it being helpful, because, as said, nasty/snappy comments are the most prominent problem. Yet, they appear pretty close to the other, "static" indication. So: I could live with keeping it, but then I wouldn't mind the "dynamic" indicator(s) to be dropped altogether.

Comment: There are *three* indicators, not two.  The user car, the comment textbox, and the answer textbox.

Comment: @Servy True. Guess I didn't mention that one explicitly, as I really have no hard opinion about it.

Answer (score 26):

> I'm not going to comment about the idea itself, just about the icon

To me the icon showing the flat palm looks like a stop symbol, as if I am doing something wrong when trying to help a new user by posting a comment or answer.

[image]

But you don't want to stop me from helping, do you? I think you rather want me to pay attention, so I suggest to replace this sign by something that says "Attention", for example an exclamation mark:

[image]

Or an "information" icon (as suggested by @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog):

[image]

Comment: Flip that bottom sign upside down, and you've got a great neutral sign.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Would also be fine for me.

Comment: I hadn't seen it like that, but now you mention it, it is superficially similar to the [prohibition signs used in forestry](https://forestdepot.co.uk/products-page/forestry-signs/do-not-climb-on-timber-stacks-forestry-health-safety-sign).  But the motion marks and lack of crossed circle definitely make me think of a welcoming wave rather than a warning here.

Comment: Yes, the icon really sucks (no better term here) and yells "Stop. Raus. Go away."

Answer (score 26):

This New contributor indicator seems entirely superfluous since the Code of Conduct applies while interacting with *everyone* and doesn't distinguish new users from the not-so-new users. Regardless, since the indicator is apparently helpful in making the site more welcoming and there's no specific reason why the site should *not* be more welcoming to the not-so-new users, I suggest using the corresponding Contributor indicator for the latter, like so:

[image: Contributor]

It is not clear to me why the company would spend development effort to support the attitude of "I would have been nicer *if I had known* that the user was new". There's a much easier solution to that problem: be nice to everybody.

Analogy time: I wouldn't have driven over the speed limit *if I had known* there was a speed camera here. Hence, there should be a road sign saying "speed camera ahead" so that I can take care to avoid crossing the speed limit there.

Of course, if you drive below the speed limit at all times, you wouldn't have to worry about the speed camera at all. Moreover, placing such road signs increases cognitive load on *all* citizens, including those who follow the speed limit at all times.

Comment: As a long time user who still gets rude/condescending comments, I support this 100%!

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Of course! I think SE got carried away too far with their Welcome Bandwagon this time. While I am certain this wasn't their intention, the "New contributor" indicator seems to suggest that being nasty with *everyone else* is somehow less of a problem ("You are not a new contributor, how come you haven't read the help pages?" type of comments) ... or at least, some people will interpret it that way. So, we just end up replacing one problem with another.

Comment: I imagine the intention was to remind people to be patient in explaining how things work because this person's new and Stack Exchange works differently to other sites, if that was the case, that got totally lost in translation to the point this is completely speculative of me.

Comment: @doppelgreener That is also fine, but there's no specific reason to be *not* patient with not-so-new users. Honestly, I couldn't think of any reason why interactions with new users should be different from interactions with everyone else. Let's say a 100k rep user posts a comment wondering why his question got closed. Why can't we explain it to him just as we would to a new user? There's no reason to be nasty with comments like, "you have 100k rep, you should already know this, you idiot!'

Comment: Yeah, totally fair to say. On per-site metas I experience established users still learning about parts of our process they'd never encountered before.

Comment: Related (in a good way): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/replace-accept-rate-with-citizenship-level

Comment: @Shog9, actually that seems more related to just https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252641/307622 for everyone.

Answer (score 25):

I think this has the potential to brutally and horribly backfire.

It has been my experience that in some subcommunities of SO, and in some other sites in general, your only hope of getting accepted as a new user is to not act like it. You're expected to know your stuff, you're expected to "separate yourself from the chaff".

I think there'll be a small but critically large enough contingent of people who have been waiting for this for a long time. We've had calls to implement options to automatically ignore questions from new users for a while, what do you think these people will do with this new information?

Maybe I'm too pessimistic about this, but I have a feeling that the occurrence of "first post, instantly downvoted and closed, and completely shut out" is going to increase with this rather than decrease, at least in some subgroups of Stack Exchange.

Comment: The solution would be to confront and/or muzzle the few people who give SO a bad name, but that's highly unlikely.  Buying into the mythology that only an asshole can be a good techie..

Comment: _"what do you think these people will do with this new information?"_ - for me, it causes me to stop and think a bit harder before down-voting and/or entering a short comment.

Comment: For me... it has no impact. regardless my first course of action is looking for a close reason and users with this banner are more likely to ask questions that fit one. Since we can't specifically search for questions by these types of users, it won't have an impact on my actions.

Comment: @BryanOakley You should be voting based on the quality of the post.  If you're not downvoting a post that you think is bad just because the user is new then *you're doing something wrong*.  SO specifically is telling you that you *shouldn't* be doing that because of this.  We want votes to reflect the quality of posts, not the age of the authors.

Comment: @Servy: _"You should be voting based on the quality of the post. If you're not downvoting a post that you think is bad just because the user is new then you're doing something wrong"_ - I wholeheartedly agree. However, having a notice that helps remind us that maybe we should take a moment to reconsider a downvote rather than just downvoting and moving on seems like a good thing for the site as a whole.

Comment: @BryanOakley Why?  Why do we want people to hesitate before giving  useful and accurate feedback?  We already have a serious problem of people not downvoting enough when they encounter bad content.  Getting people to be that much more hesitant to downvote stuff that they actually think is bad is harmful, not helpful.

Comment: @Servy _"Why? Why do we want people to hesitate before giving useful and accurate feedback"_ - because that pause may help us to give better feedback than just a downvote. I don't know about  you, but my goal here is to help people. Sometimes a friendly comment is more useful than an immediate downvote IMHO.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well SO's been trying to go out of their way to make it harder and harder for people to comment, and to discourage people from commenting as much as they can.  They think that new users think it's "unwelcoming" to be told that your question is problematic or how to fix it, so they've been making lots of changes to encourage people to just vote and not comment.  I'm not a fan.  Also, providing a comment on how the post can be improved doesn't prevent you from casting a vote to reflect your opinion of the quality of the post.  You can do both.  You don't have to choose just one.

Comment: _"Also, providing a comment on how the post can be improved doesn't prevent you from casting a vote to reflect your opinion of the quality of the post. You can do both. You don't have to choose just one."_ - yes, I am aware of that. I think this notice is great, because it reminds me to pause and ask myself if I can do better than just downvoting.

Comment: @BryanOakley But you said repeatedly that you're *not* downvoting posts that you think are bad just because you think the user is new.   You didn't say, "When I think the user is new I'm more likely to post a comment explaining how to improve the post, when I think it's a bad post."  Had you said that, I wouldn't have replied at all.

Comment: honestly this notice is just a flag to **not comment** because the person is most likely to just target you with their frustration of the other people that down vote as well but are smart enough to just *vote and move on*. So you make yourself a target to the very people most likely to take down votes/close votes as personal attacks. This just reinforces to never comment on low rep questions/answers as to not become a target of their frustration.

Answer (score 23):

My two cents; this is obsolete. As mentioned elsewhere, isn't the amount of reputation a good indicator of the SO-experience of the account? And more importantly, shouldn't we always be nice, and shouldn't the code of conduct always apply? Or...

[image]

Comment: Reputation is a measure of participation and how well received that participation is by the community, not necessarily how experienced someone is with the SE way of doing things. If you look at my reputation here on Meta without looking at my profile, how experienced would you guess I am with SE? Now look at my  profile and see if your guess was right or not. (This would have been a more dramatic example a couple weeks ago before one of my answers got up-voted, but I think you get the idea)

Comment: "Shouldn't we always be nice?" Of course, we should, but people keep forgetting this when noobs are involved. Dealing with newbies require patience, they don't get a lot of what we assume to know already.

Comment: @ColleenV, I think something like https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252641/307622 for general users might make more sense.

Comment: @Wildcard That is a better measure of participation, but I don’t think it matters, because I don’t think that we should identify newer users so we know who needs educating. I think we need to know who has recently made the leap from just reading to actually posting so we can say “glad you’re here new-to-us user, hope you enjoy the site. Here’s some general information you might find helpful.” That sets a tone for future interactions and may make some folks more willing to see comments as helpful instead of critical. (IMO)

Comment: @ColleenV Well, 'new' as defined here is 'one week following their first post'. If I assume everyone with less than 100 rep to be 'new' I think I have a very accurate proxy. Probably I have quite some 'false positives'; people who have less than 100 rep but are on SO for longer than one week. So worst case scenario I'll be slightly too nice to a few people?

Comment: I don't think so. Look, newbies who have 1 rep also can just ask 1 question or post 1 answer and gain rep very fast in a few years if the question is good. It is very rare, but a [example of this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20919/polish-spaces-in-probability) on MathOverflow where the user counts as a newbie since he only asked a question and nothing else, then left that site right after he asked the question. But the user has 200+ rep and that is not considered new because as you say newbies have less than 100 rep and this user has more than 100 rep.

Answer (score 23):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Change the text to "New contributor on Meta" if the user is only new to the meta site.

I'm okay if the "New contributor" applies to meta sites separately from main sites, because meta has a very different culture from main sites (see [this meta.so discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372907/1896169)). However, it's jarring to see a user with a large amount of reputation marked as a "New contributor", which seemingly implies that the user is new to the pair of sites in general.

Comment: Also requested here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314509/update-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-meta-to-say-new-contributor-to-meta

Answer (score 20):

> Stereotype
>
> In social psychology, a stereotype is an over-generalized belief about
>   a particular category of people. Stereotypes are generalized because
>   one assumes that the stereotype is true for each individual person in
>   the category.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype)

Your application of stereotypes to new users and others adds to the toxicity of Stack Exchange.

Comment: So what, though? Hard to see how a waving hand icon will hurt those new users who are already super competent programmers, other than getting some well-intentioned "welcome, friend" fluff and advice. Surely they'll survive that. No?

Comment: I don't get what you're suggesting. Are you trying to say that the whole concept is harmful and should be discarded? Or can you propose a modification instead to kind of tone down the assumption that new users are going to mess up.

Comment: this has been discussed in other top answers

Comment: @Chair, careful, peterSO is a new contributor.  :P  (Which I think illustrates several problems with this "new contributor indicator" all by itself.)

Comment: @Wildcard Hehe I'm tagging you and simultaneoously staring at several banners telling me that peterSO is a new contributor. Anyways, With 222 rep, peterSO doesn't really count as new any more.

Comment: It is not a stereotype but a data-driven metric. Please do not conflate the two.

Answer (score 19):

Seems like a fairly reasonable thing to do.

If I could offer a suggestion, it may be worthwhile to bump the notice after long periods of inactivity. Say a user posts a question, then disappears for 6+ months before their next post. They may have technically been a user for 6+ months, but in reality they've only interacted with the site on 2 days, 6+ months apart. Or perhaps it would be beneficial to show the notice for the first X posts?

Not a deal breaker, just my 2¢

Comment: I would highly recommend 1 year as the line in the sand; if their last post (Q or A) was more than a year ago, it's probably a good idea to consider them a fresh face for the purposes of this notice. Probably good to place that whole check within an if statement that only runs it if they have fewer than, say, 5 or 10 answers total, though (if someone has a bunch of answers they may be quite well-versed with the site and not need that notice when they come back from a Stack Exchange sabbatical)

Answer (score 17):

To a discussion in the comments about leaving the shoes outside,
I'd like to contribute the idea of access to the room only if shoes are deposited.
This will frustrate maybe those who'd wish to leave their footwear in the car or something like that but in the most part, you won't have anyone wearing shoes where they're not supposed to.

I call this concept, the door is the shoe rack. No access without a shoe deposit. You may have noticed all sites on SE encourage you to login before you partcipate, it's the same concept.

Also, I am very much sympathetic to [Iain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147520/iain)'s genuinely stated remark:

> When are you going to put some effort into making the experience **better for the people who answer questions** but have to wade through a river of [bleep] to find anything interesting ?

He's genuinely pointing out to us that there currently exists *way too much* clutter in finding interesting content... and I'm very sure he isn't talking about things which are subjectively interesting. We all face the issue and many are simply too numb to bring it up and talk about it actively these days.

Mahatma Gandhi once said, "*You* have to be the change you wish to see in the world"
A particularly drudging or boring part of any SE site can be livened up by *your* Q&A!
Ask questions that interest others to not only read and upvote but genuinely answer with the best of their capability.
And when you are in the process of writing such an answer, keep in mind that you are not only adressing the OP but also the entirety of the Stack Exchange community from diverse backgrounds, varying interests and absolutely different experience levels.

Statistics regarding users, questions, tags and such are very much often dealt with at Dawg's Waffle Haus, a room a I hope everyone at some point considers visiting. @ashleedawg would like visitors, I suppose.

[sth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/56338/sth) echoes my idea that regular users need similar benifits or nice-ities to them.

> How about instead doing some research how to **give your long term contributors a good experience**? That might be a good idea if you want more long term contributors.

As a decade old user of SE (I was here since SO started in 2008), I still feel brand new. Perhaps, it's the new accounts I'm forced to make once I forget old passwords beyond retrieval. But I think it more has to do with the parts of the site whose culture and growth I was not able to be part of. No one is omnicient enough to have been part of every conversation but truly, every conversation here stands as a mighty reminder of how much every SE community has grown and grown well.

And this one from [Andras Deak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/313143/andras-deak)is quite a remarkable read:

> I find this new feature in its current form insulting. **It implies that the experienced users can't be trusted to act like decent human beings, and that they have to be extra decent with new users.** It all doesn't make sense. The blog post, the intrusive comment flag icons, the "thanks for flagging, we're sorry you're offended" popup, and now this...I can't help but feel criminalized. Is this worth it all?

To you, Andras, I can only say...No, it's not worth it. Everything made is made with only bestest of intentions and it is not difficult to see that once the new Code of Conduct was established, it became essential that new users feel a fresher and more vibrant air, lighter and friendlier than the rest of us in the community got a chance to experience. A better UX through a better community.

***

```
I wish to slightly digress and talk a a bit about the new app called Brainly.
```

While the idea is nice and implementation beyond satisfactory, the community is absolute trash. Yes, they give the right answers most of time but they also don't in a *lot* of cases. If the user base of SE and Brainly were to switch places, Brainly would become heaven-like as a Q&A system...and SE would burn to the ground as it was being piloted by the equivalents to actual monkeys that [bleep] on typewriters until they make ca-chinky noise. The answering of questions is hard work anywhere but the effort should not be taken if nothing of quality is able to be said.

***

```
In a future update of SE, I'd like the ability 
to embed room invite boxes and comments into my answers. 
Also, it would nice if I could answer a question 
using embedded ppt slides. 

Have a ton more requests but please
get started on these for now, please.
```

***

Answer (score 16):

After living with the indicator for a while, I think that it is a good feature, but it needs refinement.

1. **It's too intrusive.** A friendly waving hand and "New Contributor" label on the user badge should be enough.
2. We are expected to be nice to everyone, so **the CoC link is off-putting** and detracts from what I think the real purpose of the "New Contributor" label should be—letting the community know that someone who hasn't participated here before has taken the plunge and might be feeling a little unsure of how they will be received.
3. The indicator should **take into account the first visible post on either the main site or the site's meta** - the goal should be to try to highlight people who are new to the community.
4. We may want to make the algorithm a little more sophisticated and **maybe take into account how long someone has been visiting the community before they posted**. If I've been lurking for a year and just now had a reason to post, maybe I don't need the "new contributor" label. Maybe I get a "emerged from the shadows" label instead ;)

I think that viewing the "new contributor" indicator as a warning that we have to treat that user extra special nice is not the right perspective. We should be thinking of this like a new team member at work being shown around and introduced to everyone. Say hello, give them a tip about how things work around here, and maybe say you're happy they're on board. In short, make them feel welcomed and optimistic that being part of the community is going to be pleasant.

It is *hard* for some of us to walk into a room full of strangers who already know each other. Even if no-one is overtly a jerk to us, if everyone ignores us, or just talks to us to tell us that we pinned our nametag on the wrong side, it's not an experience we would look forward to repeating.

Answer (score 14):

Generally, I have agreed with the approach being used thus far towards the whole "welcoming" mantra. We should provide the same level of help to new users as to experienced users, and in my opinion that level of help should include courtesy where logical, and perhaps a cold shoulder when not. It seems to me there is a certain degree of zeal when dealing with questions across the board, and while there is definitely more ground to cover progress is being made with regards to dialing that zeal into more realistic expectations.

This feature though, I am not sure I agree with, for several reasons. Primarily, I disagree with the idea of labeling users like this. I don't think it will help, and I think it has a large potential at alienation or increasing friction in certain places.

Remember when we used to show acceptance rates? It was all fun 'n games for those who had a high rate, *but*, if you had a low rate... watch out. Eventually it was removed because users with low rates were being treated harshly based on the rate, regardless of the content they provided. Which, coincidentally, is the problem here: labeling users makes it about them instead of about their content.

*Moreover*, what about all those 1 rep users who no longer have the shiny "new user" protection banner? They are still 1 rep, and now that is almost an invitation for users who may have more zeal than most to step in and *really* remind them, right down to the snarkiest possible statement, what we don't like here, and how they fit into that. Not really that welcoming...

I don't really see a flip side here to be honest. The upside to this whole endeavor is that there is a reminder banner telling us to greet new users? To be honest, I think the community *is* welcoming, and overall the process of making sure everyone is dialing their approach into something more friendly and less jarring is working due to the diligence and outlook being provided by the team.

Let's not take a step backwards with this.

Answer (score 13):

I'm...not sure about this.

There are a few reasons. Some of the voices I've heard here and elsewhere seem kind of actively hostile towards new users. And, well, at least a few users are probably going to target "new" users because... I donno, they think it's the right thing to do in some perverse way?

And if someone's post needs a fix-up, or somehow is found to be wanting, or they just need a hand with their spelling, grammar, and use of certain confusing words like "its", their reputation does not matter.

We also have the First Posts review queue.

If we're going to *experiment*, I'd suggest putting this as a privilege for a certain degree of reputation (especially since its purely cosmetic, and I can read someone's reputation), *or*, if it's not too much work, give it for getting a badge on the new user review queue, so folks who've proven to an extent that they can and do review new user posts can work.

This is an L plate (or maybe a P plate) - its letting us know that this person dosen't know as much as we do. Some people will give way cause they have an L plate. Some would have done it anyway. Some will cut infront of them cause its funny.

We don't need an L plate to help someone in whatever way we can.

Comment: I have a feeling in some tags on SO the workflow for some users will be "New user -> downvote -> close -> delete" without reading. Yes I don't think it's a hyperbole. I'm glad I'm not a new user in one of those tags today, it's like painting a target on your back.

Answer (score 12):

As a pragmatic UX point: At least on Math.SE, the "this is a new user" banner on the answer box tends to look a lot like the dynamic "a new answer has been posted" banner, according to the part of my brain responsible for peripheral vision.

I've already lost count of how many times I've had a question open, trying to figure out a solution to it, and then suddenly "seen" that, oh, someone else thinks they've cracked it, let's check what that is -- only for it to be the new-user banner instead.

At least make sure they have different colors ...

Answer (score 11):

I think that this signpost has the potential to help people target new users - in ways that can be good or bad. I don't know for sure how things we'll play out, and whether the good bits will outweigh the bad bits, so I don't think I can support this change, or oppose it.

- **Canned comments: Good!** On a couple of sites I use, we have [lists of comments established site users can write to new contributors](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6452/627). For instance, a common one on Worldbuilding that uses magic links is

  > Welcome to Worldbuilding, (Insert username)! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

  We use these . . . a lot. Ideally, on every new user. They're especially useful because [we're making the Sandbox more accessible](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464/627) to new folks, and this sort of thing is an easy way to point them to it. Having a "New contributor" sign quickly highlights potential targets for these comments.

  Really, the big advantage of these *isn't* the links to the tour and help center - those can be off-putting and might be easily ignored. But canned comments linking to things like a site's Sandbox (if the question might need some fixing), or to the site's tutorial on LaTeX (if there's poorly-formatted equations involved), or to a site policy on how to write a great question specifically about the subject the user is asking about - more specific canned comments than the generic one above can be really useful. And this a way to find targets for them - although [BJ's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/274942) might be even more useful.

  By the way, these can be done easily using [the Pro-Forma comments script](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) (kudos to Cai for pointing this one out).
- **Edits: Good!** New users are often unfamiliar with tags, for instance, or code formatting, or links, or equations, and sometimes need to have these pointed out to them. Again, this is a signpost to posts that could probably use some extra editing from community members who are willing to help.
- **Close and reopen votes: Bad?** This is coming from a different angle, but new users often don't have a good idea of the scope of the site. This means that their questions may easily be duplicates, off-topic, or unclear. If the "New Contributor" sign is shown in the New Questions list, or on the frontpage, folks will know that the question *could* be close-worthy. On the flip side, the question might later be reopen-worthy if the user responds well to feedback.

  I have to wonder whether this is going to lead to people downvoting and close-voting more harshly, or if it's going to lead to people being less harsh with close votes and downvotes. The latter *wouldn't* be great; *downvoting and close-voting is good when appropriate, not bad*. So I think there's potential here, but I'm also slightly worried that it'll impact community moderation for the worse.

I *will* say that I wish there were ways to make the helpful links more . . . obnoxiously obvious, but places like the help center and tour aren't always visited by new users. Early posts are the best way to guarantee that they'll see them - provided we get the comments in early.

Comment: What's the shortcut key or combo key to get the auto comment displayed ?

Comment: @JonH We typically copy-and-paste directly from the meta post, from what I know. There are a number of different selections, and it's stuff we've written ourselves - not an feature SE made for us.

Comment: Darn that isn't really friendly - I mean copy pasting that is...

Comment: @JonH It would be nice if there was something built into the system to let you do this with a click. I don't know if anyone's built a userscript to do so - I wouldn't be surprised, honestly. And I don't know for sure what everyone does; this is just the easiest way for me to do it.

Comment: But there aren't a lot of homework questions at that site, right? Someone with a deadline (homework or otherwise) is probably more finicky.

Comment: Understood I've seen others do it...there is probably a user script for it.  Wouldn't be difficult to do anyhow, maybe a predefined list of them.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yep, we definitely don't have to deal with homework questions a lot (although we have in the past - there was one . . . surprising case). That said, if a user's only here for homework and won't stop to read much, then there's little we can do but make the information as big and visible as possible. And I'd bet comments are much more effective than, say, the tour in those cases.

Comment: @JonH there is [Pro-forma comments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) for that

Comment: @Cai Oh, that's really helpful. I see I have a new userscript to install.

Comment: The "Pro-forma" looks interesting. That would be great if there was a Flag "Question/Answer could be improved by ..." and clicking on it leads to a sub-menu with things like "Question Unclear", "Wall of Text", "Lengthy Greetings and Intro/Background, before getting to the Point", etc. Clicking on one of those would leave **one** comment and subsequent users clicking on the same thing would upvote the single comment (as would directly clicking on 'upvote the comment'). Then everyone could easily contribute a predefined polite comment that "It would be so much better if you ...".

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and say that more proactive closing isn't a bad thing, at least on SO.

Answer (score 11):

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

I just noticed that the new contributor status is tracked separately for main and meta site. This means that established users on main would still be marked "new" upon their first post on meta. Is this intentional? It raised some eyebrows on my side.

Comment: Yes it is intentional.

Comment: @TylerH source?

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314479/253521) requesting it be changed (or the wording adjusted to reflect "new to Meta") is tagged as [meta-tag:status-review] by Joe Friend, who also has a comment below the answer supporting that. There's also [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314472/what-are-the-exact-criteria-for-the-new-contributor-indicator-to-be-shown#comment1030518_314476) also by Joe that indicates it is intentional because he says this kind of change isn't critical "*because experience on one site doesn't 100% transfer [to other sites]*"

Answer (score 11):

Going with the "student driver" analogy: when an unlicensed driver borrows a car, pulls onto a highway, and causes an accident within seconds, what do you do? Do you give them a "be nice to me; I'm new" bumper sticker? Or do you get that menace off the road and enforce licensing laws that ensure people only drive in a safe and responsible manner?

The questions that would make veteran users fly into a rage if not for a hand-wave icon are not the kind of questions the site needs. Those questions already exist, with millions of duplicates. Good questions - the kind of questions that make veteran users think, "wow, that's a good question that I can't answer myself with 30 seconds of Googling; I'll be interested to see an answer from an expert in this framework so that I can learn today" - don't need the "sorry, I'm new" sign, regardless of who posted them. Wasn't that the key of SO? Content over subjectivity?

This new element just underscores the fact that this site values <s>millions of new advertising targets</s> new users who post garbage and will disappear as soon as their homework is done for them (until next week's homework, with a new account) over <s>a few veterans with ad blockers</s> long-time users who *contribute* to the site with their time, energy, and expertise.

Comment: "Good questions - the kind of questions that make veteran users think..." - The difficulty of the subject material should not be the discriminating factor in question quality. The problem with bad questions generally is that they are either incomprehensible, a multiple-step work order, or else fail to demonstrate an attempt to **apply problem-solving skills to knowledge already demonstrated**. Heaven help someone who can't figure out that `FooError` means an error caused by a foo. But may Stack Overflow help someone who doesn't know what a foo is.

Answer (score 10):

Can they dress themselves?

[image: Poor Tim]

The user ought to be able to click on their '*newbie banner*' and **dismiss it** if they choose. That would remove the biggest complaint we see about this change - labeling.

There is also barely enough space after "Check out our Code of Conduct." to squeeze in "See the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)." and have even treatment for all. People whom have been here for over a week know the user has a low reputation for whatever reason and understand that they can click on the avatar to determine if they contribute elsewhere, the new user doesn't need the reminder and a special label.

If there are things new users ought to be doing, be it the Site Tour or reading what is *on topic*, then a pop-up reminder just for them should be helpful enough. Persons not needing such coddling should know that their actions are subject to scrutiny.

When you introduce someone to your friends you don't say: "This is Tim, he is new, so take care in asking ..." - do you? Just treat everyone normally. An opt-out [X] might be useful.

Answer (score 9):

The problem you are trying to solve, is not a new user problem. It doesn't matter if you're a newb. This community, like any, has nice people and not-so-nice people. My feedback is to read [BJ Myers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator/314304#314304) answer and implement it for everyone, not just newbs.

Answer (score 9):

I don't like label like this showing near my avatar. It offends me because it's implying that I require some "special" treatment.

I don't visit SO often, but have my share in adding stupid questions (and probably will have more). I don't see why pointing some things out is bad, unless it is addressed to the OP's personality, or insulting, etc. Feedback is usually useful, especially at the earlier stages of something.

Agree that this is redundant and not useful at all.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314474/add-a-way-for-users-to-opt-out-of-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-their-own-p

Answer (score 8):

Edit in response to the discussion I had below.  I don't spend a lot of time caring about the rules here.  I simply decided one day to contribute answers to a stack on a topic for which I have knowledge and experience.  The issue with the comment flagging system is there is no point penalty.  People cherish their internet points.  People get upset when their answer is downvoted without a comment.  People post answers as comments to avoid potential negative point impacts.  In the stack I contribute to we have long time users who habitually post bad and/or mean toned comments, that I flag, that moderators deal with.  The moderators have some ability to hand out disciplinary action and partial bans.  I understand completely the difference between bad and unacceptable, I understand completely the potential misuse of awarding negative points for flagged comments; and I understand that I'm going to lose points when mine are flagged.  This solution dances around the obvious fact that MOST of the negativity here occurrs in the comments, and impacting people's very precious point accrual is the best way to add incentive to niceness.

---

The ability to vote negatively on a comment would do FAR more to curb the meanness and nonsense that this silly indicator seems to seek to address.  There is a voting system to promote good answers and bury bad ones.  The voting system also awards internet points to the positive contributors as a reward mechanism.

The fact that users can run a muck leaving useless comments with virtually zero repercussions or negative feedback is the issue.  If my opinion means anything, I'd say that comments need a downvote function that buries and disables the comment after some threshold is met and the weight should be more than -1 rep point; and should not disappear if the comment is deleted.

Far and away my biggest irritation as a contributor to a stack is the useless peanut gallery comments, that can be overly curt at times.  The bulk of the "meanness" I've ever seen addressing new users comes in the form of comments; typically related to a question being off topic.  If you want users to temper their tone when addressing other users, including new ones, the incentive system should include a stick on all content that's contributed; not just questions and answers.

The people answering questions are far and away the most valuable part of the stack model.  There is no shortage of questions out in the ether, there is no value without answers.  I've spent a lot of time answering questions on one of the stacks and at times toy with disassociating my answers and deleting the account.  I don't even have words for this move to warn the question answerers to "be nice because this person is new" and the fact that my answer here includes that "new contributor" banner is inane.

You want positivity?  First, let users punish bad comments.  Second, remove the barriers that exist in the current bounty system to allow users to award eachother additional points for good answers.

Comment: Hi new contributor!  Wait a minute....  (That really is quite intrusive, isn't it?)  But what I wanted to say is, transferring internet points—can't you already do that through awarding a bounty?

Comment: What you suggested is already possible via flags.

Comment: @user202729.  No it's not, because there is no stick.  I am suggesting a stick.

Comment: @Wildcard, kind of.  As far as I'm aware, I can add a bounty to a question that doesn't have a selected answer after some period of time, then that bounty can be rewarded to the person who is selected to have "answered" the question.  What I think would help is if I could simply give a good answer, whether or not it's considered to be "the answer," X of my points because if my internet points are an indicator of anything it's that I am aware of what constitutes a good answer for a given stack.

Comment: @quid, no, you can award a bounty to any answer you choose.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/307622

Comment: @Wildcard I just checked a question on the money stack and there is no "add a bounty" link.  https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/98868/buyback-split

Comment: @quid: "* I am suggesting a stick.*" First, flagging is a stick; it removes bad comments, and moderators can sanction users who repeatedly make them. Second, sticks can be used against you as well as for you. The last thing we need is to have pro-new-users and pro-status-quo sides fighting it out with comment voting.

Comment: Flagging is not a stick because there is no punishment.  A stick is a punishment.

Comment: @quid: "*there is no "add a bounty" link.*" You can only add a bounty on a question that's 2+ days old.

Comment: @quid: What part of "moderators can sanction users who repeatedly make them" doesn't seem like "punishment" to you?

Comment: @NicolBolas Remove that barrier to rewarding a bounty with that barrier in place the feature functionally doesn't exist.  And the fact that there is no punishment makes it seem like there is no punishment.

Comment: @quid: "*And the fact that there is no punishment makes it seem like there is no punishment.*" And the fact that moderators can issue punishments means that there are punishments. Just because they don't talk to you about them doesn't mean they don't happen.

Comment: So we can run around in circles or you can accept that I am suggesting that there should be more immediate punishments given out by people other than moderators the same exact way that users can punish bad answers.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I'm reminded of Heinlein's passage (in *Starship Troopers*) about "training" a dog without ever smacking him for piddling on the floor because "he's just a puppy, he doesn't know any better," until one day you notice that he's a grown dog and *still* not housebroken, so you whip out a gun and shoot him dead.  (It was in the context of discussion of velvet gloves used on juvenile delinquents in the 20th century history in-universe, followed by capital punishment of adult criminals.)  Yes, comment bans are a stick, but there's not exactly a lot of fine tuning available, is there?

Comment: @Wildcard: "*Yes, comment bans are a stick, but there's not exactly a lot of fine tuning available, is there?*" Which is why moderators can warn users too. What I don't want is the ability of a random user to harm another random user just because they decided to say something that random user 1 didn't like. By keeping moderators involved, it prevents this.

Comment: @NicolBolas Then why not get rid of the voting/internet point system all together and just let moderators handle everything?  This is not different than the voting system on questions and answers and it is comments that are the home for the vast majority of negativity.

Comment: @quid: Questions and answers are the primary content of this site. Determining their quality is important. Expressing gratitude for good content (ie: reputation) is important. These are not important for comments, as these are not the tools by which content is delivered.

Comment: And somehow the comments are the source of the negativity this new indicator seeks to curb.  The first point listed in "what can I do" is report nasty comments. 
 Why not just empower high rep users to punish nasty comments directly?  Of the four things listed in "what can I do" two address comments, one addresses not piling on to a bad situation (presumably in the comments) and the last encourages addresses upvoting questions.  Seems the comments are the area of toxicity.

Comment: @quid: "*Why not just empower high rep users to punish nasty comments directly?*" If this "welcoming" discussion has taught me anything, it's that "high rep users" cannot be trusted to correctly identify "nasty comments". Oh they'll identify many things, particularly rude behavior directed towards people who are trying to offer assistance. But they have far too much tolerance for rude behavior directed towards people who aren't aware of how SO works to be trusted to identify it.

Comment: @quid: Lastly, you don't seem to recognize the difference between "bad" and "unacceptable". "Bad" content gets downvoted; "unacceptable" content gets flagged and removed. The issue with comments is about "unacceptable" comments being posted. The correct course of action is flagging, not voting.

Comment: I'm far from a new user in need of welcoming.  We simply have a philosophical disagreement about comments; this has nothing to do with you being right and me being unable to recognize some nuance.  I think that  there needs to be a mechanism to deduct points due to comments.  That can mean something like one downvote equals a one point deduction or something like five flags gets you a 50 point deduction.  Comments should not be free of potential point impact.

Comment: there are already *down votes* on comments, they are just not displayed, you flag something that needs to be removed, if enough people do that it gets removed by the system. Also if it is severe enough they get penalized for it. It is just not public knowledge.

Comment: A flag is not a down vote.  There needs to be a direct point impact.  I understand how the system works now.  I've flagged tons of comments, I notice them disappear.  I disagree emphatically that this is effective.  I think it is very ineffective.  I think it has lead to this very silly newb banner band-aid.  I think it is hilarious how people cling to the existing rules or assume that I simply don't understand what a flag is.

Answer (score 7):

My main comment is about the perceived problem and the criterion identifying new users:

- First, it's almost always obvious when a user is new to the site. I normally look at the reputation and that hardly ever fails to give a good indication (I can't imagine that one can get experience on the site without accumulating more than 10-30 rep)
- This was mentioned by others: age of first post is just one of many criteria. As an example, I don't really know whether I'm doing something wrong with this very post. I'm both old and inexperienced on this site. It's because of the rules and the expectations of those correctly considered as experienced. What they expect is right, I'm ignorant, although it goes without saying that feedback should be kind and constructive. But the fact is I must get educated.

And regarding the problem:

- Being a welcoming site is only one part of becoming a friendly site.  Further, being told that a user is new doesn't ultimately rouse the genuine kindness this community is hungry for (and I'm not saying it's futile).
- Experienced users also have an excessive sense of belonging. This doesn't just show in interactions with new users, but also among themselves. So yes, users get unfriendly towards posts, not users; but making the site friendly takes far more than making the interaction with new users friendlier.

This is a sign that practical steps are being taken to improve the overall attitude on the site, but, even in the face of the many complexities that you've mentioned, we have a long way to go.

I would just add:

- Make a system of giving positive feedback to new users (maybe a badge after `x` "useful feedback acknowledgment" given by new/experienced users) - "feedback" concerning proper use of the site. In my opinion, this will increase the awareness of the need to be kind in general
- Extend this in some way to experienced users. While this is community-driven, I think that we may in fact be supposing too much that *experienced* users are likely to use the site correctly. Giving a modicum of "voice", probably not "power", to new users may be a way to start managing the bias. New users and experienced users jointly make this site useful.

Well, I have to say it, I'm not sure I know all the rules, so I'm practically new here.

Comment: The problem with using reputation is that there are a TON of users with low reputation who are just... Bad at this. They're not new, in some cases they've posted quite a bit... They just haven't posted anything particularly *useful* yet. So if you assume low-rep == new, then you very quickly start to assume new == terrible. If you want to avoid bad posts, filtering out posts from users with < #RepThreshold# is a reasonable approach; but if you want to welcome new users to the site, posts from low-rep users is gonna burn you out. We kinda made this mistake with the Help & Improvement review.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree that improvements is needed in posts by new users. But new users are part of the community, so the solution shouldn't take into account just/primarily the perspective of experienced users. As a community, I wouldn't strive to eliminate bad posts by new users, I would strive to increase good posts by new users. That's a different effort altogether. But your explanation of the problem makes perfect sense. Thanks

Comment: @Shog9 I wonder if this will create a new sort of identifier (low rep + not new), that may bias the community against interacting with the type of user who may need the most help. I'm not saying I think it will necessarily, but the idea occurred to me when I was reading your comment.

Comment: I'm not sure that we can provide a place to help the folks who need the most help, @Don't. I *am* sure that it isn't a Q&A site.

Comment: @Shog9 sorry, I meant specifically people who need the most help learning how to use the site, not help with whatever specific thing they're asking about, or just generally "need help". I know there's a reasonable limit to how much help we can give them, though.

Comment: It is nothing but obvious when a user is new to the site with the cycle of dropping and creating accounts in each new question.

Comment: The problem is that the *problem "contributors"* are not contributors. They do not care about learning how to use the site properly or *"contribute"*, they only care about getting what they want want spoon fed answers to their endless stream of duplicate questions with as little effort on their part. If they wanted it quickly, they would learn to use the site properly, because there is ROI in that. This is a solution in search of a problem. This is the ultimate X/Y Problem incarnate.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It's supposed to be a community. If some of those that meet the criterion of "experienced" are *"problem contributors"*, then either there's a fundamental problem in the system or your view is just one of many subjective views (you being a good contributor, commenting about problem contributors). If you believe that the system doesn't need to be fixed, then I suppose we have to live with an unbalanced community where experienced members eternally complain about inexperienced ones. But my opinion is that new members are as much part of the community as the others.

Answer (score 4):

Where I can understand why you are making this change I cannot see how it is going to help really. We already know the user is new to the site based on their rep. So having a redundant indicator is just clutter on the screen that is not needed.

I can think of a possible better use for this than simply being new to the site. Maybe have an indicator that shows the person is new to the TAG instead. For example I am not new to python and at this point have around 6k rep (Stack Overflow). However I am new to VBA so maybe my questions could have already been answered but I just didn't find what I needed before asking my questions about VBA code or I just lack the understanding of the syntax to get the job done.

As you can see maybe a notification like this could be useful for people new to a tag but at this point it is simply redundant for indicating new users.

Another possible option is to instead prevent new users from asking questions in the first place before reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or similar guidelines for other sites. Maybe not force the user but strongly suggest they read the guidelines before posting.

It is not really even a matter of being kind to the new user. If a post is a bad post it should still be treated as such so the "Be Nice" has no baring on how the post should be treated. With bad post we already link to stuff like "How to ask" and the "MCVE" and when a post is closed it has helpful information telling the OP why it was close.

Really reminding people to be nice to new users is something that should already be applied to all users. Being nice is the default desired behavior and not just for the new user. Actually seeing this notice makes me think its only an issue for new users but not so much for veterans.

Comment: "We already know the user is new to the site based on their rep". Not true. There are new users with lots of rep from one action that still don't know the site too well. There are also people that have been here for years with little to no rep.

Comment: @chevybow Little to no rep is a very clear indicator that the user is most likely new and/or not knowledgeable in the sites guidelines. Sure there will be a few outliers that spend most of their time researching and not posting questions/answer but at that point they should know how to post a good question/answer. When you have a person with low rep and their post is "bad" then it its likely they are just a new user.

Comment: @chevybow: The only way either of those situations will trigger the new indicator is if any posts they made have been deleted. If this is the case, they aren't a "new" contributor. They're a "nearly post-banned" contributor.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's my point. They wouldn't count as "new contributors" but by looking at their rep you would assume they are new.

Comment: @chevybow: The indicator doesn't help with this, because it's willing to call someone with 5 deleted posts and none visible a "new contributor" when they next post.

Comment: @chevybow People that earn a ton of rep within a few days is *very* rare.  Given how much you've used the site, you've most likely never come across one.  This feature isn't worth it just so that when you come across the one in 100,000th user that got a ton of rep off of their first post you know that they're still new.  It's just so rare that it's not added value.  For people who've been around for years and have no rep, an old account doesn't mean an *experienced* user.  If they haven't done things to earn rep, they haven't experienced enough to not be "new".

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for crating the SO "New contributor" hell.

Ever since `handle "New contributors" with kid gloves` became Prime Directive on SO, people keep creating new accounts daily to get everyone tiptoeing around them while flooding the community with low quality content, you have to waste your valuable time to sift through, and contributing nothing... good job.

Comment: Is there any evidence for this? How do you know that people are frequently creating new accounts? If you can provide some evidence for this, I think it might be helpful for getting things changed.

Comment: One data point I can imagine to test this theory: use SEDE to graph the distribution of questions asked per user, and how that changes over time.

Answer (score 2):

### **I think this is a good feature <sup>1</sup>**

Almost every other answer has been negative, so I'm going to add a positive note. It absolutely has changed my behavior already. I'm a 200k rep user so I've been around the block. I've written thousands of answers and no doubt just as many comments, if not more. I write answers not because I like the game of garnering rep points, but because I truly like to help people. I've been answering questions on the Internet literally decades before Stack Overflow came on the scene.

I like to think I'm a fairly responsible, conscientious contributor, but I also know that I get awfully tired of bad or low quality questions that show absolutely zero effort, and that weariness colors my responses. I tend to downvote quickly, and I suspect that some of my comments may sound off-putting to others even though I think they are reasonable in my own head.

Seeing these reminders has really helped me pause for an extra few seconds to think about what I'm about to post. Whether it's helped me make better answers or better comments, I don't yet know. What I do know, however, is that it has helped me to think a bit more before responding to a new user, and that's a *good thing*.

<sup>1</sup>I think the idea is fantastic, though I think the implementation needs perhaps a bit more work. There's a lot of new stuff added where maybe just a single icon, badge, or banner might do. Still, I've enjoyed being notified when I'm answering a new user. It makes me feel good, and I think it has helped me to write a couple of better answers.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank: interesting. For me it's an instant downvote repellant. Why do you instantly want to downvote a new user instead of helping them learn how to be a positive contributor to the site?

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank: but _people_ are (arguably) the solution to  "∞ questions coming in all the time". The more people we can get who stay around, learn the rules, and become contributors, the better the site will be, and the more we're able to handle the influx of questions.

Comment: @BryanOakley If those people want to curate, sure.  But those people will *already* be here, because they put in the effort to learn and adapt.  These new users we're currently targetting will probably have less propensity to invest and maintain the site.  Either way, though, it generally doesn't scale; we already get far more questions than we can properly curate, so increasing that number isn't going to help.

Comment: To counteract the instant upvotes said indicator will influence.

Comment: I agree that an indicate might be helpful but only for the right kind of indicator. I think a "New User" indicator is much less helpful vs say a "New to TAG" indicator.

Comment: @BryanOakley Downvoting bad content is in no way contradictory to helping a user be a positive contributor to the site.  Providing accurate feedback on the quality of their posts is how they learn whether they're doing something right or wrong.  In fact, by refusing to provide accurate feedback on post quality for new users, as you're doing, your making it *harder* for them to learn to become positive contributors.  If you want to comment and provide even more detailed guidance, by all means, do so.  Voting accurately in no way conflicts with that.

Comment: @Servy: _"In fact, by refusing to provide accurate feedback on post quality for new users, as you're doing"_ - what do you mean "as you're doing"? How do you know what I'm doing? I guess we disagree on the point that a downvote is "accurate feedback". Or, perhaps we disagree on whether the goal should be to provide _accurate_ feedback or _helpful_ feedback. I'm definitely a believer that we should give helpful feedback.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know what you're doing because you're *telling everyone* what you're doing.  If you're not doing what you're claiming to do here, then sure, I don't know, but I'm believing you when you say you're voting based on how new the author is instead of the quality of the content.  And yes, apparently you think that fraudulently voting in ways that are contrary to the posts usefulness is actually "helpful".  I personally think that claiming that a bad post is good or that a good post is bad isn't helpful, and that giving people *accurate* feedback on a post's quality *is* helpful.

Comment: @Servy: _"I personally think that claiming that a bad post is good or that a good post is bad isn't helpful,"_ - I agree with you 100%. I think you are completely mischaracterizing what I've been saying. I vote purely on the quality of the question. _When_ I vote, and whether I give a simple comment or perhaps a more longer comment, may depend on whether I know that the user is new here or not. If I think someone is new here I plan to work a little extra hard to make them feel welcome. _I will still downvote bad questions_, and still use my power to close questions that deserve to be closed.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well you've said the exact opposite *many* times throughout this thread. This is the *first* time you've said that you don't actually vote differently based on whether the user is new or not.  Even including the comment you posted just before that one, just a few hours ago, where you said that you don't think voting accurately on the quality of a post is helpful.

Comment: This is the little answer that could! It keeps getting voted up to zero or one, then back down to negative one, then back up to zero or one, then back down... I think I can, I think I can! I'm quite surprised about how much some people really seem to hate this idea.

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate any new ideas that add real value to the community! But I am wondering

> **what's the added value of this new feature!!!**

---

**I also have two main notes:**

1. **The attention message in the answer section**

**Actually**, I don't think you need to say for someone who tries to help, *be nice*!!

He/she comes to help so he/she is a **NICE** and his/her contributions should be appreciated.

> So **the attention message in the answer section does not show any type of respect!**

---

2. **The New contributor alert below the new user avatar**

As contributors, most of us come here for **helping** all as much as possible in a nice and professional manner **regardless** of the type of user, his/her nationality, his/her religion, his/her color, etc.!!

So we don't care about the type of contributor. We care of providing a good answer in a nice manner that should help the OP to solve his/her problem **regardless** WHO IS HE/SHE?

**That will lead to**

- The new contributor will be happy because he/she found a good answer that helps him/her to solve his issue.
- He/she will come back to ask his/her new questions because he/she **trusts** this community!

> **In this case,** the community achieves one of its main goal that is **TRUST**.

---

**But** this trust will be nil if the community does not also care about:

> The contributors who provide good answers without any type of
>   appreciation and feedback from the OP as well as the community, This
>   makes them feel disappointed. I think this will lead to **`many unanswered questions and a few of new contributors!`**

So, I hope also the community and all contributors to take care of the good volunteers and appreciate their effort and time by providing innovative ways to encourage them to continue as well as by altering the OP with different ways to appreciate the provided answers in case it helped him/her!

> If you are looking for good volunteer continuity, increase your **appreciation** for it,

---

**Let's summarize the above points:**

- `New contributor alert` is useless, we already know this info from his/her reputation!
- The attention message in the answer section is not suitable and does not show any type of respect!
- The community should think about new features that guide the new contributors how can use and appreciate any type of help!
- The community should think about new features that increase the trust.
- The community should think about new features that appreciate the volunteer's effort and time like tangible awards, please check [Is there a tangible award for the Most Active Contributors in SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298558/is-there-a-tangible-award-for-the-most-active-contributors-in-se)

Comment: Are you suggesting pushing new users to upvote more? or am i completely mis-understanding the point here

Comment: I talk about there points, 1. **helping** all as much as possible regardless of the type of user, his/her nationality, his/her religion his/her color ....etc!! **2.** guide the new contributor to appreciate the provided answers in case it helped him, most of the new contributors didn't read the welcome tour guidelines so he get the answer without mark it as accepted , some other get the answer and mention in comment thank you without Mark the answer as accepted so we must find a practical solution to guide them how can accept the answer in case it helps.

Comment: **3.** we should also care about good volunteers who provide good answers, wh should find any way to appreciate their time and effort!

Comment: Sounds like just a request for reputation.

Answer (score -2):

I like this, but my gut feeling says that one week is way too short. How about a larger timespan?

Also, that time span could be cut short if a certain number of posts have been made, on the theory that continued posting indicates the user is becoming increasingly familiar with the site.

Comment: Welcome, new contributor!  I see you've been a Stack Overflow user for nine years.  Now what was it you were saying about one week being too short?  (Note for future readers: yes, this post has the "new contributor" indicator on it.)  :)

Comment: Even on meta, I'm seeing @JensBannmann as a Member for 5 months.

Comment: @martin it starts counting on the first post, not the moment of account creation.

Comment: @JAD That explains it then.

Comment: I agree with Jens...instead of phasing out the "New Contributor" badge for a user after one week since s/he first posted something, how about making it last until the user has posted N separate times instead? The N variable could be 3, for example.

Answer (score -9):

From my experience (and perhaps it relates to my personality), a more important point than articulating good comments is to help novices understand these two things:

- The downvotes on *well-input* questions
- The close votes as unclear or off-topic on "crystal clear" questions

A novice cannot have the perspective of the experts to see why their questions are unclear, yet however hard the experts explain the novice cannot understand it, to the point of satisfaction. I think, if the experts see that the only way for the novice to understand is to gain more knowledge and experience in the field, then at least they should say so, so that they can at least stop wondering what's wrong with them.

As [@Masked Man said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator/314355#comment1031172_314355):

> This is actually a reasonable answer, and I'm disappointed to see some users calling it "off-topic". The maximum new user complaints pertaining to the hostility from the site result from the downvotes (especially downvote piling) and closing questions. The nasty comments are a distant third on the list. Since the stated purpose of the new contributor indicator is to make the new users feel more "welcome", it is worth questioning why the top 2 complaints aren't being addressed by it.

<sup>For example, see [Why is the question asking about views on logical quantifiers off-topic?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28610/157643), [How to ask the question about Poincaré's quote about mathematics?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27727/157643) (require 10k rep in Math), or [What to do with seemingly anecdotal questions but actually because of lacking of terms?](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2338/12937) in Psychology & Neurosciences.</sup>

Comment: This problem still bugs me as an experienced user, so I think it's suitable to speak here. Why is it bad?

Comment: I don't think it's bad.  (And I didn't downvote this answer.)  I just don't quite see how it relates to the question at hand.

Comment: @Wildcard my answer aligns with [Magisch's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314410/260800) (not an exact duplicate though)

Comment: See how you get voted down for complaining about getting voted down? This place is rotten.

Comment: @StefanReich Meta voting culture is a bit special that way. Although you'll get downvoted on main too for complaining. Generally speaking talking about not liking downvotes in some way is gonna get you downvoted in some weird variant of the streisand effect.

Comment: Maybe the downvotes are because the Ooker is complaining about downvotes however I think the downvotes are more related to this answer being off topic in the sense that SO's post is about the new user feature and not about the downvotes and close votes features.

Comment: Voting is a bit awkward on Meta.SE because users are encouraged to vote based on agreement / disagreement, but it does affect your rep. It's kinda weird. What exactly does rep even represent on Meta.SE? Popularity?

Comment: @Mike-SMT no, I complain about the confusion for cannot pinpoint what exactly is wrong with the well-input *questions*, but asking around the experts cannot give a satisfactory reason. I think the new feature is a way to solve this problem, and I want to talk about it.

Comment: @Magisch I had to google streisand effect. Too afraid to ask here ;-)

Comment: This is actually a reasonable answer, and I'm disappointed to see some users calling it "off-topic". The maximum new user complaints pertaining to the hostility from the site result from the downvotes (especially downvote piling) and closing questions. The nasty comments are a distant third on the list. Since the stated purpose of the new contributor indicator is to make the new users feel more "welcome", it is worth questioning why the top 2 complaints aren't being addressed by it. Perhaps the answer could say that a bit more explicitly.

Comment: @MaskedMan I've slightly edit it, what do you think? (I don't know what to add more)

Comment: @Ooker I think this is much better now. Of course, *I* immediately understood what you meant, I just hope the edit makes it clearer to others. :-)

Answer (score -9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I like this - it's helpful, and not too intrusive.

I think that a "new user" indicator could also be useful when reviewing suggested edits: if a new user's post has been changed, could we (edit reviewers) be alerted that the OP needs extra guidance?  We could then pay extra attention to the quality of the editor's comment.

Ideally, we'd also be able to improve the edit comment (assuming the edit itself is worthwhile).

Answer (score -15):

I am on the side of Tim and SE staff that new users are not treated properly in SE. Some pro users are really rude with the new user when they make a mistake. Although, the rudeness should not be tolerated against any user, but the new users are extremely vulnerable to that.

Even if there is no rudeness in comments or answers, there's an indirect form where they get downvotes and closed/deleted questions without much of an explanation.

I have seen people complaining about this behavior of SE community at other places such as Quora, devRant and various Facebook group. I am managing a team of new coders at my work and whenever I ask them to post their questions on StackOverflow they get scared to death about it. It also happened to me.

So the point of the above text was to acknowledge that there's a problem (contrary to what I can sense in some other answers) even if you're not actually involved in it in any way. Now the next point is whether the provided solution is a good one or not.

I am not so much excited about the new user tag. It's good that SE knows about this issue and trying to solve it. While the new user tag is solution directed towards the existing users asking to be nice (which would be great if they do), I agree that they might get overwhelmed with all the welcome comments (Being too nice).

There're few suggestions I could think of to make the experience better (Feel free to agree, disagree or improve on them)

- Workplaces have the buddy system for new joiners. We can take that idea and use it. For eg., having a separate chat room for newbies where they can ask their dumb 'how to' questions and will not receive the scary downvotes. The buddies there can help them direct towards right FAQs on how to write good questions and probably edit their existing ones.
- Have a preference for opting out of all those new user functionality. It will be helpful for pro users with multiple accounts or experienced use joining a new SE site.
- Speaking of which, the new user features should consider the experience in all the SE sites, so that joining a new SE site doesn't bring unnecessary help for an experienced user.
- Probably consider showing the label when downvoting or closing a post written by a new user too. Having some text is always useful, even if it's somewhat rude. Having your question downvoted or closed without any explanation is much ruder. It should just remind the downvoter to add a useful comment.

**Update:**
So, people actually do not agree that newbies need some special treatment. "Shouldn't we always be nice?" Of course, we should, but people keep forgetting this when noobs are involved. Dealing with newbies require patience, they don't get a lot of what we assume to know already. Just have a look at [this post on devRant](https://devrant.com/rants/1620622/so-eventually-they-understood-a-lot-of-so-users-are-assholes). It's really common there to call SO guys a**h*les. If there was no problem which needed to be addressed, then we shouldn't be receiving this title.
Somebody even suggested an ad block setting in the answer to block the label. Seriously? That's really ignorant.
My suggestions could be dumb here, but at least get out of your cult-zone and try to see properly. Why not you aactually talk to a new programmer and without helping them, just ask them to try to get their issues resolved by asking questions here. Probably you will acknowledge the issue.

Comment: There was a mentorship project, not sure if SO (the company) intends to continue it. A buddy system / mentorship system could work nicely for the smaller SE sites. For SO (the website), I think it doesn't scale - which is sad.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I think having a separate chat room should work. The SO UI can just add a link of the chatroom in the 'ask question' page. I am not aware of the mentorship project though.

Comment: Chat could work, but again the problem is scale. Filling a chatroom with new users is just shifting the problem - far more new askers than people able to help them. It could work if you can filter the new question askers effectively. You'd want only those genuinely interested in improving their questions in that chatroom. But how to create that filter, that's the hard part.

Comment: I just entered mainly Unix&Linux around 2 years ago, and have now 40k. If people would be so hostile to newbies, newcomers would not be able to build reputation as I did.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank There're many posts about that in various forums. This was the first result in my search on Quora - https://www.quora.com/What-is-bad-about-Stack-Overflow Apart from that I have mentored a team of new coders and they all have bad experience about SO. I don't think there's any post (surprise me) where they felt welcomed by SO.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That's really great. However, my personal experience is mostly about StackOverflow. People complained that it has become a cult (Please check my earlier comment on it). Not so sure about Unix & Linux SE though, although I don't see any reason it won't turn into a cult either, probably in future if adequate measures are not taken.

Comment: @noob We also have our share of people making the same complaints about Unix&Linux. Often the most vocal are long time low rep users. IMO it takes work, a lot of energy and time, and some are not willing or cannnot keep up with the effort, and then wonder why their questions are not so successful in the gamification of the site as others. It can take up to 30-45 minutes to write a good question, and my high voted answers often represent hours of effort, both in improving the English, and improving the technical side.

Comment: perpetuating the myth that down votes, close votes and anonymous votes are *rude* is what needs to change. How you spending some time educating people that this is not the case instead of reinforcing the rhetoric that it is *mean*, or *rude* or *malicious* in anyway when it is not. How about helping educate new users to be more patient and respectful of the people giving them **free** help and actually follow the instructions/advice left in the comments instead of complaining about it and calling people names and posting *down voter explain!*.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson So, at least you acknowledge that there's a problem there somewhere which needs to be addressed. I am using SO for 7 years now and it took me a while to understand that downvotes can be good too. They seemed rude when you're new, probably that's the reason Facebook never added a dislike button. Just imagine if people tell you on your face that they don't like what you said without explaining why? Won't that be rude? Why not here? We oldies know that it's a feedback process, but new users can't understand that. They already have a lot of rules to understand when they start.

Comment: nope I acknowledge no such thing that you are inferring. I will say if something *seems rude* to you, and objectively it isn't, it is *you* who has the problem taking anonymous activity on the internet as a *personal affront*, nothing more.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Do you know that even if I intentionally reply with something with super rude or abusive here, that'll also count as an activity on internet too? Not that anonymous, as my profile is linked with my real home address (if you are keen to find it). And it's not just me, SE staff agrees that a change is needed. And I found this post on devRant which tells that at least 400 people agree with me https://devrant.com/rants/1620622/so-eventually-they-understood-a-lot-of-so-users-are-assholes

Comment: @noob - read for comprehension, clicking an voting arrow on this this is **anonymous** activity that you are perpetuating as *rude* behavior if someone does not take precious time out of their short life to explain their reasoning to someone who will at best not care and at worst and most probably just attack them because it has now become **not anonymous**. You claim down voting without comments is rude, I am telling you that is **your problem** that you are inferring personal affront and neg meaning to something that objectively has none. not the person that anonymously clicked the arrow.

Comment: the corollary to that ridiculous link you posted is that the number of people that post questions that deserve the same label or even worse outnumber the complained about`1000:1`. Using a troll site like that as **proof** of your argument just disqualifies it even more so because [Appeal to Popularity](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/40/Appeal-to-Popularity) on top of the already fallacious [Appeal to Emotion - "Think of the Newbies"](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/29/Appeal-to-Emotion) and .

Comment: besides that troll link is just [Confirmation Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) of the most obvious and worse sort. Just the fact that site brought you hear means you had already made up your mind. Go head preach to the choir that thinks the same, and more and more people like myself who have quit answering questions because I do not want the lazy people as my peers ( or my peers peers ) in the future will quit soft moderating the site and it will just approach *Yahoo Answers* entropy that much quicker. I have wasted enough of my time on this at this point 10X over.

Comment: I actually agree with the fact that we need to deal with SE's reputation but I disagree with most of the rest of your post. For instance, *even if there is no rudeness in comments or answers, there's an indirect form where they get downvotes and closed/deleted questions without much of an explanation.* Ignores the fact that the new policy and statements by SE seem to be to just downvote or close and leave no comment. Note, when I see the new contributor indicator I find myself less likely to leave explanations or advice because its not worth my time to deal with flags for being unwelcoming.