# Show whether "new contributor" has taken the tour and/or read help pages

Tags: feature-request, help-center, tour, new-contributor-indicator

The ["new contributor" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator) sounds potentially useful. I'd find it more useful if it told me

1. Whether they've taken the tour (e.g., do they have the `Informed` badge)
2. Whether they've viewed the *How to Ask* page
3. Whether they've viewed the *On Topic* page

...so I can tailor my comments on questions that need improvement to suggest doing so if they haven't, and so I don't tell them to do so if they already have.

This will be particularly useful as, with September just around the corner, the number of new contributors will get a bump for a while...

Comment: This makes me think of [one of the side-effects of showing the accept rate](/q/66773/318307). It might inspire lots of annoying _"Not answering until you take the tour"_ comments. If you leave that information on the profile page, maybe only people who genuinely want to help the user would look it up and leave a comment.

Comment: @AndrewMyers - I think the community has moved on a **lot** since then and that's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the good intentions here, but it doesn't seem worth the developer time to add this feature. What percentage of new contributors have taken the tour and done any of those other things? Very few according to the number of users with the "informed" badge. **Furthermore,** how many people with the informed badge actually read things, versus just scrolling through quickly? Compared to the *vast* number of new contributors each day, this feature request would just be adding more information to the "new contributor" label for a very small percentage of the new contributors.

Also, if you really want to know if they have the "informed" badge, you can click on their profile and see their badges.