# Why did Stack Exchange remove the "last seen" feature?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, calendar

Old profile page:

> [image]

New profile page:

> [image]

Why did Stack Exchange remove the "last seen" feature? Also, the statistics "last seen" and "member since" are no longer displayed when I visit other users' profile pages.

Comment: @KazCalihan Welcome to Meta SE. Regarding removal of the "Last seen" feature, I ask about this specifically in my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368289/562482) to that linked question.

Comment: @Spevacus The new buzzword for today is "vanity metric", it replaces the "member since" and "number of views", but one's person "vanity" is another's treasure. The parent post may explain what happened to but not "why".

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: They may have followed the *Indie Hackers* podcast too closely. It could have been [episode 196](https://share.transistor.fm/s/49e988df) with David Perell; I am not sure about the exact episode.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: OK, it *is* [episode 196](https://share.transistor.fm/s/49e988df) (2021-03-17), at ***39 min 50 secs***. [Direct MP3 download](https://chrt.fm/track/EB7BD2/media.transistor.fm/49e988df/0f2557ef.mp3). [RSS feed](https://feeds.transistor.fm/the-indie-hackers-podcast).

Comment: @P.Mort the expression must've been coined earlier than of March this year because none of the speakers hesitated to ask what "vanity metric" meant or where the phrase was from. Still thanks for pinpointing the exact time. Interesting buzzword.