# Why was it decided to no longer show how long a user has been a member of the community?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, statistics, user-experience, personal-statistics

The user profile page of Stack Exchange sites usually used to have a "**Member For**" field showing how long a user has been a member of the community. Ever since the profile page has been redesigned, I can only see this for my own profile. Why was it decided it to no longer show it?

#### Update

The field has been since [restored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive#comment1229175_368328).

Comment: I'm not sure that "It’s a vanity metric and we don’t think it’s worth keeping around." is sufficient explanation to count as answer to the question. It's very thin and maybe there could be more rationale. For example reputation is vanity too and it's not clear who is we.

Comment: I agree with @Trilarion, the dup is basically saying "*We removed it because we don't like it*", which is not a satisfatory answer, IMO. I'd like to see a more complete explanation, with all the reasoning that led to all those info being removed. Unfortunately I can't vote to reopen, so I'm just commenting to show support for this question.

Comment: So they could add it back and then claim to be listening to feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive)

Comment: @bad_coder:  I cast the final vote on this question to reopen it *away* from that dupe.  It doesn't address the issue of "why".  "Because" isn't quite good enough for an answer on this one.

Comment: And that's why I voted to [leave it open](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/79109).

Comment: The reason was given briefly in a single word, without expanding on it. If the designers had wanted to elaborate they would have. If threads get started for every change asking **why?** then the original announcement threads will all be duplicated multiple times asking for a justification of every sentence or bullet point. (How easily this does fly depends mostly on how prominent the OP is on MSE.) So no, this question doesn't stand on its own 2 feet and should be asked under the canonical (where it has been asked several times already both in the answers and the comments).

Comment: I'm 72 years old, my memory banks are failing and I have no  backups.  I kind of appreciate it when someone reminds me of something that I no longer have the slightest clue of any more.

Comment: @bad_coder if this occurring often is a problem, isn't there an easy solution in simply doing a better job of explaining changes? or better yet, releasing them in a way that allows feedback *prior* to them being implemented network-wide? Shutting down feedback just because the company failed to adequately prepare is absurd. They are free to respond here or on the main thread, neither has occurred yet. If they responded on the announcement thread, then it would make sense to close it as a duplicate. This isn't a slippery slope.

Comment: @KevinB how many threads asking this same question were closed in the past 2-3 days? Maybe a dozen?! The objection you raise is [the same as ShadowWizard's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368367) and so far employees have been addressing issues in the comments on the canonical.

Comment: @bad_coder sounds like they chose a poor dupe target

Comment: @KevinB no I don't think so. (Until now it's a split vote, 7 users voted to close 5 to reopen). As they say *democracy in action*.

Comment: @bad_coder Yes, I do think it sounds like they chose a poor dupe target.  Those who've VTRed - myself, Makoto, hkotsubo, Kevin - have all [given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368435/why-was-it-decided-to-no-longer-show-how-long-a-user-has-been-a-member-of-the-co#comment1229124_368435) [explanations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368435/why-was-it-decided-to-no-longer-show-how-long-a-user-has-been-a-member-of-the-co#comment1229291_368435) as to *why* we've kept it open.  The duplicate doesn't address the question asked here, and that's why it's a poor dupe target.

Comment: @Ollie linking to comments in the same thread doesn't add anything. I've given the opposite POV which the majority of voters so far share. Besides, this question can now be closed as [no longer reproducible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive#comment1229175_368328). Since the decision was reverted within a couple of working days I don't expect (or ask) a dev to write an essay after the fact. Neither am I inclined to keep a question with 3 sentences, a dozen closed dups, about an issue that lasted 1 weekend.

Comment: Undoing the change doesn't answer why this occurred, nor does it make the question "not reproducible". You can easily go to the linked question and see that the change occurred.

Comment: I do remember full blown answers from Shog or Tim but it seems that nowadays it's much more common that official answers are very short and/or hidden in comments.