# Performance delay in editor when moving to a blank line

Tags: support, editor, firefox, performance

I initially thought this affected MSE only, but now I started to face the same issue on other SE sites.

I've encountered/reproduced only on Stack Exchange on Firefox for Win 10.

---

Place cursor at the start of a paragraph:

> [image]

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice, and try to move cursor up using the <kbd>↑</kbd> key:

> [image]

Huge delay is faced when moving the cursor up one or two lines.

I asked [in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=9015045#9015045) a couple of days ago on how best to report it, so if there's any data the team here needs, let me know.

Note: I can repro *most* of the time, and it only affects (as far as I've encountered) jumping **to blank lines.**

---

**Update:** Based on two comments, the issue affects Firefox in general, though as demonstrated in another comment, it doesn't affect Wikipedia; for the time being I've rolled back the addition of the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag until the issue becomes more clear.

Comment: This is just a visual lag. The cursor actually moves instantly. I initially assumed this was just a Firefox bug…

Comment: I can confirm this problem. Firefox version 92.0 on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) (but with [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment))), with a spell checker. The problem started a few days ago. I thought it was the spell checker as it can be quite CPU intensive on some (long?) pages, but apparently not.

Comment: And: 1) Using [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript), only allowing the necessary domains to get JavaScript code from. 2) An unspeakable number of tabs 3) Rotating rust (yes, I know) 4) On all sites I have tried, but not on all arrow up/down key uses, approx. every 4th (or it may be time based, like slow every 5 seconds), but it is somewhat intermittent. 5) Total CPU load is light, less than 5%, and the CPU load doesn't shoot up when it slows down. 6) Not out of physical memory (though Firefox is a beast) 7) 4G/LTE connection

Comment: Can you check if it happens in Firefox in any textarea outside of SE?

Comment: @Cave Johnson: There aren't any problems with the main editing window for the Wikipedia article *[4G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G)* (about 300 lines and 55 KB).

Comment: It is especially pronounced when moving to an empty line (with up/down arrow keys). The delay can be up to about 2 seconds. [Sample post to try it on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely/2003515#2003515).

Comment: Re *"one blank line to another blank line."*: It also happens when going from a non-empty line to an empty line.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q: yes that's a better description, I've updated, thanks

Comment: The problem persists (2021-09-19). I think this should be retagged as a [`bug`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/info) (instead of [`support`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/support/info)).

Comment: @P.Mort: Done. And yes persists here as well.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q deciding factor for me was simply turning on Violentmonkey. Almost no tabs, PC running smoothly otherwise. Also on a 3G. All things considered this hadn't happened before using the same setup and there haven't been any OS/browser updates in the meanwhile (that I have noticed, version numbers are the same last I recall). It also started happening for the posters here around the same time, so I suspect some change on SE's side is causing this.

Comment: It is quite severe on [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615996) (on *TeX - LaTeX*). Though it may be a coincidence as the problem is intermittent. (You may have to wait a bit before it is available for trials.)

Comment: Unable to repro using FF on Mac.

Comment: @Luuklag: Which post did you try it on? I still get it on [the *TeX - LaTeX* one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615996). (2021-09-21T093106Z+0), e.g. using arrow keys up/down.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q, that question, this question itself, and your SO sample question. None of them caused this behaviour for me on FF on MAC. Fun thing is I'm on a windows PC right now, and can replicate. So this appears to be OS specific?

Comment: @P.Mort: It's so bad that when now typing elsewhere, when I double-enter and go up, I expect a delay! Wonder why it wasn't status reviewed.

Comment: @ymb1: It didn't get enough attention. A bounty and/or a [skit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qvi2_nb6V8E) on YouTube or TikTok  may help.

Comment: I will change my workflow to work around this by adding *another* 102-key macro keyboard (either using my own firmware based on Arduino Leonardo (making a PCB in the process, bringing it closer to actual product status) or a [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/hardware_avr)-capable one that is largely collecting dust (I repurposed [an old](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmdu0w_k-0E) Apple keyboard with, some have argued, [nearly the best keyboard Apple ever produced](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huCdi0bljgk&t=39s) -

Comment: cont’ - approximately early 1990s (the best one is from the same era) ([Alps SKCM Cream damped](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huCdi0bljgk) (dampened version of [Black Alps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvDluHoe7ro&t=4m45s)) and [PBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybutylene_terephthalate) keycaps!))) and use a text editor ([Geany](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/)) instead of the edit window (that will initially be slower, but it opens up new possibilities). No, I am definitely not an Apple fanboy, but the old stuff wasn't built down to a price.

Comment: This will also take take of the annoying [new "feature"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views/367616#comment1224912_367609) (related to the [infamous changes to the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive/368289#368289)) after the top bar became sticky where back TAB into the title will not make the visible (unless it already is). One is forced to scroll (with the [RSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury)-inducing mouse).

Comment: I just saw the same bug in Google Keep. This seems to be a Firefox bug, not a Stack Exchange bug.

Comment: And I just saw this same bug in Wolfram Alpha. Again, this is not a Stack Exchange bug.

Comment: @Sebastian: Thanks for the info, I've [asked in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9030649#9030649) on what to do in this case.

Comment: Firefox upgraded to version 93.0 today (at least on Linux). That did not fix it. The frequency *seems* to be lower, but that could be entirely due to its intermittent nature. I tested it on [the LaTeX question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615996).

Comment: As of 2021-12-29 (Firefox version 95.0.1), the problem does not appear to be there any more. Can you confirm?

Comment: @P.Mort.: oh wow you're right, thanks! was it reported on bugzilla?

Comment: @ymb1: I don't know. It would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this bug mostly on SO but also on SE (using Windows 10 Pro version 20H2 with Firefox 92.0). It's exactly as described. I'm under the impression it's not a delay but the cursor blink that isn't reset when you change line. It does happen most times when going upwards in the text instead of down, in the blank lines between paragraphs and code fences.

I just tried reproducing it in the below example and it happened a couple of times (less than 10%). It happens almost 80% of the time when I use userscripts ([Roomba Forecaster](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/tree/master/Roomba-Forecaster), [UnclosedRequestReview](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/UnclosedRequestReview.user.js) and [SO Close Vote Request Generator](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts#so-close-vote-request-generator) with Violentmonkey).

A paragraph.

```
A code fence.
```