# Reattribute posts made by deleted account to recreated account

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-accounts

Is is possible to reattribute posts that were made by my previous, deleted account to my new account?

Due to personal issues, I deleted my accounts a while ago, but I recently remade them, and I want my old posts and the reputation generated from them (about ~600) back. Is this possible by any chance?

My old Stack Overflow user id was 16442705 ([example post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68546257)), and my old MSE user id was 1035193 ([example post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368304)).

Comment: See our FAQ [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account), section *What happens to the reputation and badges I've earned? Can I request my account be restored?*

Comment: In reference to the proposed duplicate, see the text: "You will not be able to regain ownership or reputation of your prior posts; you must start building your privileges as a new user. (Do note that if you've ever earned the network-wide association bonus rights, and you create an account with the **same** credentials you earned the association bonus on, your new account **will start** off with the bonus.)".

Comment: The first link is broken for less than 10,000 reputation points (deleted question). Can you summarise in this question?

Comment: Sorry @P.Mort., yes, I'll do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, those posts will forever be attributed to your deleted account. You are warned of this when you delete your account because the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page presents you with a dialogue box that contains this text...

> User deletion is irreversible! We're sorry to see you go. Your reputation and votes will be removed and all of your content will be made anonymous.

Unfortunately it's actually even worse than you might think as those posts can still count against you for the purposes of rate limiting and post bans. That's to stop people simply creating a new account for each poor quality question they ask ad-infinitum in an attempt to avoid all the site's quality controls.

If it's Stack Exchange that deleted your account for some reason however, there may be some wriggle room depending on why your account was deleted. Clearly if it was deleted in error they can and will correct that error but there may be other limited circumstances too.

Comment: Robert, the reason I though this was possible was my because one of my [MSO posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409356) that [I made with my previous account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/409356/1) was automatically reattributed to my new account. Can this be explained?

Comment: @user17242583 yes, but that's a different question.

Comment: @richardec It was because the post was migrated. When you (re)create your account on a given site, any posts that were migrated are re-associated to your current account. This exists so users who don't have an account on the target site at the time the post is migrated can participate in their own post if they later create an account there; that script doesn't consider if a user previously had an account there, though.

Comment: The team has made some exceptions to this, though. Users who've contributed large amounts of content and had their account deleted as underage are eligible to request prior content be reattributed if they later return to the site when they're of age.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for that info @Sonic! :)