# Pluralization bug in "Asked 1 questions"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, plurals

[image]

If you view a user's profile, who asked only one question, you will see *1 questions* under *Stats*. Can this wording be changed to "1 question"? The same is also the case with answers.

Comment: [Related bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368440/339911)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> check user profile
> "1 questions"? Can this be so?
> all good, has been fixed!