# How do I view my calendar of days visited?

Tags: support, profile-page, visited-days, calendar

I recall being able to hover over my days visited/consecutive days to reveal a little calendar of which days I was deemed to have visited the site. It looks like the profile page got a redesign sometime recently, and I can't seem to find that functionality anymore.

Is it still possible? If so, what am I missing?

For reference, indeed I did manage to find someone's question which contains an image of the aforementioned calendar: [I literally visit Stack Overflow daily but the visited calendar says that I am missing days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387040/11536796)

Comment: It has been removed. See [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](/q/368285/289905).

Comment: Aw man, well thanks for letting me know. "The consecutive visit calendar UI has gone away. This is some super legacy UI that isn’t remotely mobile-friendly. The statistic will continue to be displayed for badge-earning purposes, but I think it’s a *potentially toxic metric*."

Comment: By complete chance, I hovered over my streak just now and realised that they've reintroduced the feature! I've flagged my question I ended up closing (long story) for reopening as the updated self-answer I now wish to give is not relevant to the linked post. Hope it gets opened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

About 7 months ago, the [feature was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/539565) during a responsiveness update to the profile page. Thankfully, this feature has (recently) been brought back!

[image: Tooltip saying "Click to view daily visit calendar"]

[image: Calendar popup with days visited highlighted]

Comment: (Also, just so people know how it works: Users can view their own daily visit calendar, and mods can view the calendar for any user on the site. Beyond that, users will not be able to see the daily visit calendar for other users.)