# Failed audit adding to my Stats - Is it a Bug or a Feature?

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, review-stats

Earlier today, I failed a [review audit on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/32542044) (yes, that does happen *occasionally*). Now, I'm not here to dispute that audit – my action (voting to reopen) was controversial, at best, and possibly a wrong/bad decision (although I *will* state that I think it isn't an especially good audit, because the close reason is wrong, IMHO).

My concern here is that this *failed* audit has been counted as part of my review stats. I immediately realized this because it was the last of my daily 'quota' and, when I had dismissed the stern warning, I was then immediately presented with the "Thank-you for reviewing 40 …" message. Furthermore, my total count in [the "Review Stats" page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats) for that queue has increased by 40, today.

According to [this canonical answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/616624), failed audits should **not** count towards one's review history (and rightly so):

> Passed audits count as a successful review towards the review badges.
> A failed audit does not count toward the badges, but does not
> decrement your progress either; it simply adds none.

Note also that the progress indicator (towards my next Steward badge) was also increased by 40 for today.

So, is this a bug or a new feature?

Comment: I'd say a bug, but sadly more than once things that looked like bugs were found later to be done on purpose. (e.g. removing details in user profile)

Comment: The daily review limit counts failed audits. The part you quoted is about review *badges*, for which failed audits indeed don't count.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog  But look at the bit about the Review Stats page - My count **and** progress towards my (next) Steward Badge were both incremented. (But I'll edit to make that last bit clearer.)

Comment: Also, I *seem* to recall that, in the past, failed audits didn't count towards the daily limit. But I'm not at all sure about that because I don't fail audits that often. :)

Comment: Okay, maybe things have changed since the new review UI was introduced. I remember in the old UI that the counter would not go up with failed audits.

Comment: @Sonic Yeah, I think I've failed only around half a dozen since the new UI came in. I don't recall (either way) if those were added to my stats, so I can't really pin down when this started happening. If this is a bug and it's fixed with "retroactive effect," then I guess I may notice. :)

Comment: [A removing-details-in-user-profile reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Hmm. I just looked through the Q/A you linked (again) but failed to see the connection to this question. What did I miss?

Comment: This makes me glad I don't have enough rep on SO. I would hate to have a robot second guessing my question reviews on such questionable grounds.

Comment: @SurpriseDog Heh. Since that audit, the question has received one *real* reopen vote (maybe because of this post?) and entered the queue as a *bona fide* review. I saw it, recognized it and ... skipped.