# Websockets can be used to spy on users' activity

Tags: bug, profile-page, top-bar, privacy, web-sockets

Stack Exchange's [removal of "last seen"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive) has demonstrated that the time that users are active is considered private information. However, there are still a variety of ways to circumvent that, and I've found what I believe is a new one.

SE's websockets have a `<userid>-topbar` endpoint. This is used to update number of new items in the inbox and achievements dropdowns (though importantly it does *not* show the items themselves). However, unlike the POST requests that are used to actually retrieve the inbox items, the websocket doesn't need any authentication.

Thus, anyone can see how many unread items are in a user's inbox/achievements, and be notified precisely when the user checks their inbox, since the `UnreadInboxCount`, `UnreadNonRepCount`, and/or `UnreadRepCount` would go down to `0`. By upvoting one of the users' posts a few dozen times, perhaps spread over several weeks, one could get a pretty good idea of when the user is active.

It would also be possible to get a (less accurate) estimate of how long a user has been inactive based on the amount of reputation they've gotten since last checking their inbox.

This isn't a *huge* issue, especially since the API still reveals the exact last seen time, but I do think it's worth pointing out.

Comment: The removal of "last seen" was likely a fait accompli by the one staff member who posted that, not an overall company decision, or else otherwise they would have also removed the API endpoint.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog - worth noting that mods still see the old "last seen" time in the UI, after asking for it back

Comment: Curious, are the `<userid>-...` endpoints still working? A few days ago I tried experiencing with this in hope to get real-time notification for mobile app, but I didn't get any response. I probably tested it wrongly though.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. The `-topbar` one does, although I'm pretty sure `-inbox` doesn't work anymore. SE still seems to be requesting `-reputation` so I'm guessing that still works.