# Add a way for users to "opt out" of the new contributor indicator on their own posts

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, new-contributor-indicator

(Note: This request isn't necessarily about me; I'm also asking for the benefit of users who might want to do so as well.)

I understand that the new contributor indicator is shown on my posts on sites where my first post is not very old. However, in many cases, for various reasons, I don't want my post to be identified as having come from a "new contributor".

Is there a way I can remove this indicator from my post, or make it not show up on my post in the first place? If not, can that please be added?

Comment: Would be great if they add option to disable this indicators in settings.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Fun fact: I [proposed an experiment on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367719/experiment-request-temporarily-stop-showing-characteristics-about-a-user-in-the) that would have confirmed or denied the need for this indicator. Strange they went off empirical evidence rather than gathering it and seeing if it's actually needed.

Comment: If you're implying that SO ignores community feedback and does whatever they see fit, I'll [be shocked](https://www.reactiongifs.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/im_shocked.gif).

Comment: @AndrasDeak My opinion was that such an indicator was needed, and I was hoping that the experiment results would show that. I was just commenting about how they went off empirical evidence rather than concrete evidence.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog We are considering running an experiment like the one proposed in the question you linked to. I think the idea of hiding rep and badges is related, but gets at a slightly different problem.

Comment: @JoeFriend I imagine we could ultimately level the playing field entirely and remove the reputation system. There would be no need for labels in an altruistic community where everyone posts content with no harmful effects stemming from greedy rewards.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: And no *beneficial* effects stemming from greedy rewards either.

Comment: @Joefriend I'm just [insulted by being called a noob again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314302/are-we-creating-divisions-in-our-quest-to-make-new-users-welcome/314393#comment1030505_314393). Straight up, no chaser - insulted.

Comment: Retagged this one as [status-deferred] as it will be added to the backlog (and to ensure doing so actually bumps it into our backlog).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something that we haven't considered. We will probably let the current implementation run for a bit and evaluate the results. Then, we can consider enhancements that make sense.

Comment: Now that it's run for a bit, can we consider this?

Answer (score 26):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

*I'm all for adding this option, but want to address a second issue related to meta:*

Even if we do not get the option to remove it from all our posts - can we either have our meta's use **the same calculation as the main sites they are from** or include an option to **turn it off on just the meta sites**?

When you have users on meta with years on the site and many contributions which just don't happen to include that network site's meta, it seems like a bug when they show up as a "new contributor". And I have recently seen an 18k user show as a "new contributor" due to their first meta post.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314472/what-are-the-exact-criteria-for-the-new-contributor-indicator-to-be-shown#comment1030518_314476

Comment: I like the idea of considering the parent site when posting it on meta. We can add that to the list of optimizations we will consider in the second round. Of course, MSE isn't a child site of anything, so any new poster to MSE would be new unless we considered all other sites, which I'm not sure we should do.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, [_especially_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314474/add-a-way-for-users-to-opt-out-of-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-their-own-p#comment1030525_314474) from a [new contributor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygjm1.png).