# Disable the new contributor indicator on new private beta sites

Tags: feature-request, private-beta, new-contributor-indicator

Currently, according to [What are the exact criteria for the "new contributor" indicator to be shown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314472/377214), the new contributor indicator is enabled by default on all sites, except Stack Overflow for Teams and Enterprise.

I request that it also be disabled on sites that are in private beta. This is because the only people participating on a private beta site are those who committed to the Area 51 proposal or accessed the site from the link on the proposal.

Also, by definition, *everyone* is a new contributor on a private beta site, because the site was just established. According to the current rules for displaying the indicator, *everyone* participating in the site would get the indicator on their own posts.

Therefore, it doesn't make much sense to display the indicator on sites that are in private beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually quite a bunch of people joining during private betas. They are not as private as the name suggests. Also passive readers can turn into contributors.

Overall I don't see a need to deactivate it for private betas.

Comment: How about disabling the indicator only for users who committed to the proposal, but showing it for others? What do you think of that?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog better. Not sure the resulting improvement is worth the complexity though. It basically helps with an overflow of indicators in the first week.