# Hand wave/new contributor icon seems to follow the post, not the author

Tags: bug, new-contributor-indicator

This user (who has never upvoted or accepted an answer) has four posts, two with the new-user icon and two without:

Question 1 (2018-08-15), no icon: 
*[How to use {{ post.title }} from blog.models into home_app template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860778/how-to-use-post-title-from-blog-models-into-home-app-template)*

Question 2 (2018-08-20) icon: *[How to make a booking form in django which timeslots and dates available are customizeable on admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933943/how-to-make-a-booking-form-in-django-which-timeslots-and-dates-available-are-cus)*

Question 3 (2018-08-21) icon: *[Django __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) but from django/contrib/admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952353/django-str-returned-non-string-type-nonetype-but-from-django-contrib-admin)*

Question 4 (2018-08-24) no icon: *[Django Stripe webhook json data how to view that data in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009435/django-stripe-webhook-json-data-how-to-view-that-data-in-admin)*

Is this expected?

Comment: It's been three days. They're a veteran now

Comment: of course ;-)  but why doesn't question #1 have an icon, and why does #2 and #3 still have icons (them being veterans and all...)

Comment: Expected. Criteria here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314472/what-are-the-exact-criteria-for-the-new-contributor-indicator-to-be-shown

Comment: @random thanks for the link, I understand how it works now, but it still seems strange that the flag follows posts and not users...