# Why I am labeled as a new contributor when this is not the case?

Tags: support, new-contributor-indicator

Why does philosophy.stackexchange suddenly label me as a new contributor when in fact I have already posted many questions in the last 2 years?
It this related to deleting cookies from my pc?

Comment: Yes, it seems that you have an [old account](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/27561/exp8j). Use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have them merged.

Comment: You logged in with a different account, that's all.

Comment: @Glorfindel not sure OP wants to merge, looks like both accounts were created on purpose. (i.e. sock, which is legit as long as it's not used in bad way.)

Comment: The indicator's generally broken tbh. For example, it says "contributor" even for those accounts that are not contributing anything.

Answer (score 11):

You appear to have more than one account on that site.

While your other account indeed has many question, the account you used here has no old questions, just the one you posted today, so you're still considered a New Contributor.

Stack Exchange does not perform deep check for sock/alternative accounts, we're allowed to have them as long as they're not used in bad way, e.g. voting for each other.

You can ask to [merge the accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous), this way no longer being New Contributor once they're merged, or leave it be.

Comment: Just a quick note: if you *do* later on get your account merged, new posts you make later won't show up as "new contributor", but posts you made with the new account before it got merged [will continue to show as "new contributor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329421/recalculate-new-contributor-indicators-when-an-account-is-merged?r=SearchResults&s=1|112.6697) until the indicator expires after 7 days.