# The new contributor indicator is not appearing in a post created by a user that joined today

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-contributor-indicator, specific-site

On a site where I am a moderator, i.e. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), I was looking at [this post from a user that joined within the past day](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274954/why-is-capybara-unable-to-find-my-element). The [new contributor indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/341145) is not appearing under their username and avatar.

[image: missing new contributor icon]

This is occurring in every browser I have checked, including:

- Google Chrome Version 99.0.4844.74 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10
- Google Chrome Version Version 99.0.4844.74 (Official Build) (x86_64) on Mac OS X 12.2.1
- Microsoft Edge
  Version 99.0.1150.39 (Official build) (64-bit) on Windows 10
- Mozilla Firefox 98.0.1 (64-bit) on Mac OS X 12.2.1
- Mozilla Firefox 98.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10
- Safari Version 15.3 (17612.4.9.1.8) on Mac OS X 12.2.1

Interestingly it does appear on a new post for that same user on [their recent post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71488364/1575353). Why is it not showing on Code Review?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The post did have the indicator when it was first created. However, the user performed a merge of the unregistered account into their registered account. We [clear the new contributor status from all posts when a merge occurs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329421/posts-made-by-new-accounts-that-are-later-merged-into-established-accounts-still) because trying to recalculate whether or not to apply it to each post is too tedious.