# Update the "new contributor" indicator on meta to say "new contributor to meta"

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, new-contributor-indicator

Earlier today I saw the New Contributor indicator attached to a user who had 2,700 reputation and had been a member of the site for over 2 years. When I went to leave a comment, I saw a banner of “(User) is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct.” above the comment.

This was very confusing until I realised what was going on: this occurred on our per-site meta, and this was the first day the user had contributed to our site's meta.

Could the indicator & banner be updated on meta sites to make it clear it's not just being buggy?

- Update the “New Contributor” indicator to say “New Contributor **to Meta**” or “New **Meta** Contributor”
- Update the comment/answer banner to say “(User) is a new contributor **to this meta.** Be nice, and check our Code of Conduct.”

(Text bolded just for the sake of this feature request; don't have it bolded in the released version.)

Comment: I also was confused - see this MSO post: ["New contributor" should reflect main sites, not meta sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372906/new-contributor-should-reflect-main-sites-not-meta-sites)

Comment: I was typing up a question for meta.GDSE saying the exact same thing. It's confusing to see a user with 4K rep and a chat regular marked as a 'new contibuter'.

Comment: See [Indicate if a new contributor is new to Stack Exchange, or new to the current Stack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315047/239016). I took the liberty of  including your request in mine.

Comment: I think that for users who are new to the specific site (or meta site), but not to the Stack Exchange network as a whole, "<user> is new to <site name>" would be better than your current wording.