# Indicate if a new contributor is new to Stack Exchange, or new to the current Stack

Tags: feature-request, new-users, new-contributor-indicator

I just came across a question by a new contributor to a Stack (in this case, [SF & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com)), as indicated by the new contributor indicator. Since it was an ID request, I launched into a comment linking to [our guide on asking ID requests](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) and was about to invite them on the [tour], when I checked their network accounts and found that they had 17k+ rep on Stack Overflow.

Now I know that not everyone will welcome new contributors like that, but still, it would be useful to have an indication if a new contributor is new to Stack Exchange and may not even realise they can edit their own posts (yes, I've encountered those; self-answering just to add new information), or merely new to the current Stack and may only need a couple of pointers on topicality and tagging conventions. Likewise, someone may be a regular on the main Stack, but new to meta.

So please, **expand the new contributor indicator to indicate if a user is new to the current Stack, new to the current Meta, new to Meta in general, or new to the Stack Exchange Network.**

---

*I realise that a reputation of 101 may indicate a user having received the association bonus, so they may have some experience elsewhere on the Stack Exchange Network. However, that doesn't tell me if they're 200+ on their highest reputation account, or 20k+. The former may still need some help using basic features while the latter doesn't.*

---

*I came across a request to [indicate if someone is new to meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314509/239016). That sounds useful as well, so I've edited my question to incorporate that request.*

Comment: Good idea. I'd change the hand to have the SE logo color scheme (gradient blue, I lack the skills to create a mockup) in case the user is new to a site, but is not new on at least one other site in the network.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Someone with 17k on SO likely doesn't need any new user treatment besides special particularities of the stack they're on atm.

Comment: If done right, it might also solve [indicating if a user is new _to meta_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314509/239016).

Comment: SQB - the meta one is especially useful. Many high rep folks on sites have never really checked out meta, and the oddities therein...

Comment: @RoryAlsop I've included that request in my request now.

Comment: You already had my upvote :-)

Comment: Here's a suggestion regarding the wording: If the user is new to this site (or meta site) but has experience on the Stack Exchange network, it should say "<user> is new to <site name>".

Comment: The tour should still be linked to, as it provides useful information as to what is and what isn’t on topic for that specific site.