# Remove "be nice new user" message from users who are active in other sites on the network

Tags: feature-request, association-bonus, new-contributor-indicator

This answer is clearly not answering the question (examples before 1950), and is marked a new user, but has a 61K+ reputation on another site (stack overflow) and thus we shouldn't have to explain the rules to them like we should for a new user [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/52737/37397).  Despite [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128255/include-101-rep-users-i-e-those-with-the-association-bonus-in-first-questions) which asks us to ignore rep bonus for purposes of the first question/answer queue (and I agree with), I'd prefer we save the "new user be nice" for those users who are truely new, and not include those of us who are experienced on other sites.

@Glorfindel remarked that [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315047/indicate-if-a-new-contributor-is-new-to-stack-exchange-or-new-to-the-current-st) asks to distinquish between new users to this site versus new users to the whole network.  That information is available via clicking on the user's icon and finding out.  My request is different because I am asking that the "new user be nice" tag is removed completely from those of us who already have enough reputation in another network site to not count as a new user anymore.  Thus, the "new user be nice" tag is network wide, not site specific.

The reason I ask this is because I want to cut down on the false positives, so we don't start ignoring the "new" message because we see it too often.  Do you agree?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indicate if a new contributor is new to Stack Exchange, or new to the current Stack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315047/indicate-if-a-new-contributor-is-new-to-stack-exchange-or-new-to-the-current-st) - that *is* a slightly different proposal but with the same intentions and (IMHO) a better variation.

Comment: @Glorfindel Maybe a duplicate, but they were asking for a different sort of "new" statement, where I am asking that the "new user, be nice" be removed completely.  I'll add your link, though.

Comment: `thus we shouldn't have to be nice to them` - I think you've missed the point entirely

Comment: Hmmm.   I'll edit that to make it scan better.  The point I'm trying to make is that we shouldn't have to be *extra* nice to them.  We should treat them like any other user, be nice, but still appropriate.  In this instance, downvote or flag as appropriate, but expect them to know what the rules are, and not explain to them like they are new.

Comment: When sites have special rules (like Skeptics's citation rules), it's helpful to remind people that while this user is a rock star on SO, those site-specific rules might be completely new so don't jump on a user for not following them (educate instead).

Comment: Yes, that sentence can be made to scan better, but I think the point here is just because im active on SO, I might not be completely up with the norms/expectations of another community. Skeptics, for example, has its whole own set of rules & norms. If im new there, its helpful to know that so the natives dont leap on their every mistake. (And its no coincidence that Monica just used the same example as me)

Comment: I understand that.  In fact, the whole "new user be nice" doesn't actually add any information that can't be determined by looking at the reputation of the user.  We shouldn't need it at all.  However, if it is actually effective in helping us to treat new users better, then we should keep it.  I'm just suggesting that it may be more effective if we only use it for actual new users, and not for experienced users on a new site.

Comment: If you don't want it on your *own* posts, there is another request for that: [Add a way for users to "opt out" of the new contributor indicator on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314474/add-a-way-for-users-to-opt-out-of-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-their-own-p)

Comment: Look how much the NCI has helped you here, [you know you want this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Know_You_Want_This).

Answer (score 19):

I've been on SE for nearly a decade - am a moderator on two sites, and occationally mess up badly on a new site.

As an experienced user - I know *my* sites well but that doesn't give me expertise on other sites. I have 100k on Super User, but my first question on Skeptics needed a *lot* of help, and If I wanted to ask a question on a non-techie site, I'd be lost.

I get the *mechanics* of SE style Q&A. I may need help with the site culture. In that respect even an experienced user can demand help.

If you want to show that you are an experienced user, show it through your posts.

Comment: Hmmm, that entirely missed my point, but that's probably down to me and my lack of ability to ask the question clearly.  No matter.  I just saw a way I thought stack exchange could be made better and presented it to see if others agree.  They didn't, no problem, moving on.