# "New contributor" shows for yourself

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-contributor-indicator

Title says it all. Puzzling Stack Exchange just told me to be nice to myself.

<sub>Somehow, the page expects more text from me to submit this, so here, page, have some text. But that won't make the matter more clear.</sub>

Comment: feature. Self love is awesome.

Comment: I plan on self loving later tonight.

Comment: Wir haben andere Methoden. But instead of text fill, you could pose an actual question. Or use ASCII art - [online tool](http://marklodato.github.io/js-boxdrawing/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by design, according to a [comment by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator/314297#comment1029901_314294):

> FWIW, the extra bit of the signature block will show up to the post's owner too - so it ain't like we're putting some secret mark on their backs.