# Voting for A New Feature

Tags: discussion, meta, feature-request-process

I have seen new features being both *highly appreciated* and *highly criticized*, especially [the new contributor banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1).

I wonder will it be better if, for every new feature, the veteran users first vote if it should be made, and then only the new feature being featured live across the network?

Then perhaps it will reduce the number of friendly arguments written (for the contributor banner feature there is currently 47) and the site might be better if the choices are totally up to the community?

(I personally think, if the user is not new, that came from other Stack Exchange sites (like me), there should not be the "new contributor" banner. But then, if the user is new, I appreciate that banner)

Comment: [tag:feature-request] should be used only for actual feature requests. This is important because on actual feature requests the voting meaning is different than on discussions. On feature requests votes mean agreement/disagreement while on discussions votes means clear/helpful | unclear/unhelpful.

Comment: Ok I have removed the tag @Rubén

Comment: It's doesn't matter. As you can see by CoC discussion, SE employees don't listen the community.

Comment: @Suvitruf There's a difference between "not listening" and "not doing everything the community tells us to do". We are absolutely listening. We can't always do what you want.

Comment: @Catija that's why you have pushed CoC. Sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it would be *nice*, but practically that might result in a few undesirable network effects.

One very obvious one would be the outsized influence of Stack Overflow, as the single largest site and essentially this might drop features that benefit smaller sites more far down the priority queue.

It's also worth remembering, the occasional misstep aside, SE does rely a lot on nonpublic Q&A for funding - things like Careers and Enterprise help provide revenue for the company and some of the features they've chosen to do (and wish they would do) are based around those products.

Some changes - like the new site design process might also disadvantage older sites, which may lose their more 'bespoke' aspects but may benefit smaller sites waiting for a design and sites that move from beta in the future.

With something like the New contributor indicator, the expected impact is not with folks who are on SE now, but people new to SE. I guess the idea is to try to get new people on board, get them used to the way we do things, and hopefully retain them. There's probably a ton of stuff we don't see going on behind many aspects of the decision and well, things might not work out in a way any particular person expects.

That's of course not counting the huge amount of behind the scenes work and fixes we never notice until something breaks. These things are *essential* but not as neat as "Can we have commonmark everywhere?"

When it works, and well, our corporate overlords (Hi! <3) listen, the current model - a mix of deciding based on real world requirements, the occasional moonshot and community consultation.