# Still showing up as "new contributor" more than 3 weeks after joining

Tags: support, new-users, new-contributor-indicator

I've been here on meta SE for almost a month now, but on all my posts I still show up as a "new contributor". I've seen plenty of people who have been a member for barely over a week, but they don't show up as a "new contributor". Why is this happening?

Comment: I think the "new contributer" should be updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's confusing (especially on child metas) but according to the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314287/323179) it is:

> visible for a week following their first post

You first posted on November 9th, so that's less than a week ago.