# Are there any guidelines for appropriately welcoming new members?

Tags: discussion, comments, welcoming

When a "new contributor" makes their first post the first comment is often something along the line "Welcome to [subsite]. Please take the tour." Where "the tour" is a link.
When I saw this at first I always wondered if the "new contributor" had done something wrong since a link to "the tour" was needed. Numerous times I looked, but couldn't find the issue with their post.

Now I've come to the conclusion that the person who posted first comment is actually just doing it to be nice.

However, I think it has the opposite effect on many new users since they (like me) think they might have done something wrong.

Are there any guidelines on the site regarding this?

Comment: Nope, just people being over-ambitious about doing everything they think the CoC is expecting of them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These comments are posted by those who:

1. Want to help
2. Want to appear welcoming
3. Don't believe the system is capable of pointing new users to the ample learning resources provided on registration, and thus need to repeat this information in the way of a comment

> Are there any guidelines on the site regarding this?

No.

> However, I think it has the opposite effect on many new users since they (like me) think they might have done something wrong.

Yes, me too.

Blame welcoming? Blame the tools? Take your pick!

Comment: The tour does appear in a banner at the top of the page, but [that probably doesn't work as well as it ought to](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/120541/64022). Also, established users can't see it and may forget that it exists.

Comment: @Kevin I'm sure it's always well-intentioned.

Comment: Regarding point 3, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/307622

Comment: @Wildcard Deffo.

Answer (score 9):

I offer such welcomes on the two sites that I moderate:

> Welcome to XX SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this
>   isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short
>   [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

I do it because I want:

1. them to feel welcomed
2. to help them be successful by making sure that they have taken the Tour

I modify the message to acknowledge that they have taken the Tour when I can see from their profile that they have attained the [Informed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/informed).  I thank them for having done that.

Comment: _"I modify the message to acknowledge that they have taken the Tour when I can see from their profile that they have attained the Informed badge. I thank them for having done that."_ I never thought of checking a new user's badges before suggesting that they take the Tour. Will do that from now on, thanks!