# What kinds of questions is this tag [welcoming]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

There is a tag named [welcoming](/questions/tagged/welcoming) with 21 questions. Its excerpt says:

> For question about the Welcome Wagon, started at 2018.

Indeed, when [sorting by Newest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/welcoming?tab=Newest), older questions with the tag seem to mostly follow that guidance. The vague name, however, means the tag is used for the general concept of welcoming<sup>1</sup>. For example:

- [Are there any guidelines for appropriately welcoming new members?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334046/)
- [Should Stack Exchange slow down visitors following links from sources that are causing problems?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336329/)
- [Automated welcome message from the moderators when you join a site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357325/)

I see three possible paths:

1. Leave it alone. (There hasn't been a question with the tag since 2020, after all - perhaps best to let sleeping dogs lie.)
2. Change the tag description to make it more generally about being welcoming to users, which the Welcome Wagon would fall under. (This might make it a meta-tag, depending on the wording.)
3. Edit it out of the questions where it is used improperly. (Perhaps accompanied with a change to the tag name to make it more explicitly about the Welcome Wagon.)

What should be done about this tag?

<sup>1</sup><sub>I'm not familiar with the Welcome Wagon, having not been around then, so perhaps some of those are actually about it</sub>

Comment: Please don't do option 3. - those bumping of old questions makes it hard to see anything interesting on meta

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz done in small numbers at a time, bumping older questions to fix tags is a part of normal clean-up operations.

Comment: yes, it is unfortunately normal, this makes it not any less annoying.

Comment: @sam Staff can rename tags without bumping, I think.

Comment: Anyway I'd go with #3.

Comment: Assuming that tag is for the Welcome Wagon specifically, can the tag wiki be updated to include what the Welcome Wagon _actually is_ (as opposed to just saying Welcome Wagon)? Or even a link to a Meta post explaining it would be nice. I _think_ it refers to [this](https://stackmod.blog/2018/06/june-2018-the-welcome-wagon-hiring-new-stuff-and-the-last-gdpr-mention-we-hope/), although even after reading that it isn't clear to me what it refers to

Comment: How about we just rename the tag to [welcome-wagon] and fix the ambiguity, then, if necessary, retag the questions about "welcoming" to something more appropriate (on a case-by-case basis)? There are only 21 questions, after all - laughable effort compared to what we usually do on SO.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine that's my option 3 - I really feel I must have phrased things wrong for multiple people to have suggested alternatives which were just option 3 again. Could you suggest a better phrasing?

Comment: @bobble I've seen the option 3, it's probably *my* wording that is not ideal :) I wanted to suggest the tag name + mention that with this number of questions it will unlikely result in a lot off effort (and, consequently, won't flood the "active" page for long [on an off-note, coming from SO, I do not understand the focus on preventing mass maintenance edit efforts that are done in one sweep for keeping the tab clean - it's not like it's disruptive due to the low frequency of occurences]. But I'd still move the "rename" out of the parentheses to highlight that the rename is part of the option.

Comment: There is also the same tag on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/welcoming/info).